# Biblatex: changing the order of entries

Tags: biblatex

I switched to biblatex only recently and I'm still struggling with understanding how to do things properly. My question is: How to change the order of entries/units/blocks in the bibliography? The style I'm using is "numeric". Now, the default order is:

> B. B. Aggarwal, Y. Takada, and O. V. Oommen. “From chemoprevention
> to chemotherapy: common targets and common goals”. In: *Expert Opin
> Investig Drugs* 13.10 (Oct. 2004), pp. 1327–1338.

Basically, I need commas as separators, a comma between the journal title and the volume; "In:" should be removed, the volume and the number should have prefixes and comma as a separator, and, finally, the date should go at the end, without the brackets. Something like this:

> B. B. Aggarwal, Y. Takada, and O. V. Oommen, “From chemoprevention
> to chemotherapy: common targets and common goals”, *Expert Opin
> Investig Drugs*, vol. 13, no. 10, pp. 1327–1338, Oct. 2004.

If there is a step-by-step tutorial about how to customize bibliography or how to crate a bibliography style for use with biblatex, I'll be most grateful for it. Thanks.

Here's a code for testing purposes:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{Aggarwal2004b,
author = {Aggarwal, B. B. and Takada, Y. and Oommen, O. V.},
journal = {Expert Opin Investig Drugs},
month = oct,
number = {10},
pages = {1327--1338},
publisher = {Informa Pharma Science},
title = {{From chemoprevention to chemotherapy: common targets and common goals}},
volume = {13},
year = {2004}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}  
\begin{document}
Test~\cite{Aggarwal2004b}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Add the following to your preamble (or the configuration file `biblatex.cfg`):

```
% Commas as separators
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

% Comma before and after journal volume
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
  \printfield{volume}%
%  \setunit*{\adddot}% DELETED
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

% Prefixes for journal volume and number
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1}% volume of a journal
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}% number of a journal

% Comma before date; date not in parentheses
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
%  \printtext[parens]{% DELETED
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
%       \usebibmacro{date}}}% DELETED
       \usebibmacro{date}}% NEW
  \newunit}

% Issue/date macros removed after journal number
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
%  \setunit{\addspace}% DELETED
%  \usebibmacro{issue+date}% DELETED
%  \setunit{\addcolon\space}% DELETED
%  \usebibmacro{issue}% DELETED
  \newunit}

% "In:" removed for articles; issue/date macros added after note+pages macro
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
%  \usebibmacro{in:}% DELETED
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \setunit{\addspace}% NEW
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}% NEW
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}% NEW
  \usebibmacro{issue}% NEW
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

Note that I removed "In:" only for articles - it should still show up e.g. in an `@incollection` entry. Also note that moving the date immediately after the page numbers may be misleading (the year in your example may be mistaken for page 2004).

As for step-by-step tutorials, the best way is to a) thoroughly study the biblatex documentation and b) delve into `biblatex.def` and `standard.bbx`. For those fluent in German, there are also the excellent [tutorials](http://biblatex.dominik-wassenhoven.de/dtk.shtml) by Dominik Waßenhoven.

EDIT: Herbert has provided a [more elegant way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10682/suppress-in-biblatex/10686#10686) to remove "In" only for articles.

Comment: +1 for mentioning my German tutorials (c; – just kidding. Very nice answer! BTW, I think it would be really nice to have some tutorial in English for biblatex customization. I have no time to translate my tutorials (and bring them up to date), but it would be great if anybody wanted to do this – I could at least offer my help.

Comment: Well, guys, you just put those tutorials forward, we're all good friends with Google Translate ;)

Comment: Your answer and comments are of great value to me, lockstep. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @lockstep for conference papers how can I have "in Proc." instead of "in: Proc"?