# Suppress "In:" biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

How do I suppress the "In: " before the `journaltitle`? Like so:

> *<strike>In:</strike> Journal of Applied Physics*

Comment: Use [biblatex-apa](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/)?

Answer (score 299, accepted):

Insert after loading the package [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex):

```
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
```

or if you need it only for an entry of type `@article` (can easily extended to other entry types -- see below):

```
[...]
\usepackage{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
[...]
```

[image]

If you need it for more entry types use:

```
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
     test {\ifentrytype{article}}%
     or
     test {\ifentrytype{inproceedings}}%
  }{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}%
}
```

Comment: This isn't likely going to do what is needed, since it will also remove the "In" from e.g. articles in edited volumes, for which most bibliography styles is used.  The odd decision of biblatex's default is to use "In" with journal articles, which isn't very common.

Comment: @Alan: Yes, I think "In: " is needed for edited volumes, etc., and I do find the "In: " for journals rather odd.

Comment: @Kit I've posted a sample .bbx file which solves the problem.  It might solve your problem, or at least allow you to make your own along similar lines.

Comment: @Kit: see edited answer

Comment: @Herbert: Wonderful. Is [KU] of type `article`? What about [1]?

Comment: @Kit: in the bibliography entry is a shorthand defined for Kant, which is taken as label instead of the number. It is an `InBook` entry type

Comment: @Herbert: very nice! I didn’t know about \ifentrytype (which is not documented, as far as I can see).

Comment: @Alan, @Kit: Initially, I also thought that biblatex's default behaviour to use "In" for articles was odd. By now, I find it coherent because "the @article type could also be called @inperiodical" (biblatex manual, p. 9).

Comment: @Herbert: A very elegant code snippet -- I hope you don't mind a small bounty. ;-)

Comment: @lockstep I think we find it odd simply because there are no bibliography styles in the outside world that we know of that use 'In' for articles.

Comment: How could we extend this to @inproceedings ?

Comment: look for the "or"  operator

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to apply this two types (say, article and proceedings). Could somebody please tell me how to do something like that?

Comment: @geo909: see my edited answer

Comment: @Herbert Thank you kindly, sir for the quick help!

Comment: You can also just nest the conditionals: `\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
        \ifentrytype{review}{}{% apply to @review entries, too
          \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}%
        }%
  }%
}`

Answer (score 33):

**Please note that the accepted answer is much simpler and this answer should probably not be used**

I don't know if there's a simple way to do this within a document. The way I've solved this problem is to define my own `.bbx` style in biblatex which fixes some of its odder defaults.  This style (named here 'mybibstyle') is loaded with the `[bibstyle=mybibstyle]` option when you load biblatex. (This could be added to the preamble of your document, I suppose, but my preference for long modifications like this is not to add them to documents.  (And this is something that one will use all the time.))

Here's a sample; the code is copied from the `standard.bbx` file in biblatex.  This assumes the `authoryear-comp` style of biblatex as a starting point, and then modifies the bibliography driver for the 'article' type.  (It also removes quotation marks from article titles; remove that code if you don't need it.)

If there is a simpler way to do this, I'd be glad to find out.

```
\ProvidesFile{mybibstyle.bbx}
\RequireBibliographyStyle{standard}
\RequireBibliographyStyle{authoryear-comp} % change this if you're not using author-year
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection,unpublished]{title}{#1}%No quotes for article titles
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} % Theses like book titles
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

If your base is using a bibstyle that itself changes the formatting of the 'article' type then you should copy *that* definition into your custom bbx file as the starting point.  The relevant code to remove from the driver is the `\usebibmacro{in:}` (which is all I removed from the standard bbx version to create the one above.)

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for; many thanks! I too found these two defaults (the "In:" prefix and the quotes around article names) most odd, and am glad for a fix... who knows what influenced these stylistic decisions.

Answer (score 19):

Because it comes up very often, the [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) styles have an option to remove the "in:" only for `@article`s.

Setting

```
articlein=false,
```

removes the "in:" for `@article`s. The "in:" for all other types is preserved. See also §4.1 *General options* of the [`biblatex-ext` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear, articlein=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,pines}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Pines, Shlomo (1979). ‘The Limitations of Human Knowledge According to Al-Farabi, ibn Bajja, and Maimonides’. In: Studies in Medieval Jewish History and Literature. Ed. by Isadore Twersky. Cambridge, Mass.: Harvard University Press, pp. 82–109.//Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

---

If the "in:" should be removed for all entry types, the solution from the accepted answer

```
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
```

is still the way to go (and it isn't much more complicated than using an option).