# How to get rid of the "In:" prefix in some bibliography entries using BibLaTeX?

Tags: biblatex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suppress “In:” biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10682/suppress-in-biblatex)

In the bibliography list I have the entry like:

> Author (Year). Title_of_the_article. In: Title_of_the_Journal. Ed. by
>   Editor. Publisher, Pages.

How can I remove the "In:" bit before the Title_of_the_Journal?

I am using `authoryear` bibliography style.

Comment: This question is likely a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/4483

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry for not searching stackexchange enough. Since google reseults were very poor, I falsely assumed, that my problem is more difficult than it looks from the first sight.

Comment: No worries. This post is a few votes away from [being closed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#close). Once that happens it'll be indicated as a duplicate. That should help make the solution you were looking for easier to find.