# Is there an SBL citation style?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

Does anyone know if there exists a `.bst` file for the Society of Biblical Literature citation format? Or a `biblatex` style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SBL style described [here](http://library.bethel.edu/class/tutorials/writ-cit/SBL_Citation.pdf) is basically an author-year style; in the bibliography, however, the year is not displayed right after the author name(s), but at or near the end of the respective entry. In case you want to use `biblatex`, you should load the package like this:

```
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=authortitle]{biblatex}
```

For minor modifications that might be necessary to create a "true" SBL `biblatex` style, have a look at [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles). To remove the "In:" for `@article` entries, use Herbert's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10686/510) to [Suppress "In:" biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10682/suppress-in-biblatex).

Comment: Thanks. I found that the historian style is almost identical and close enough for my purposes. The following command gives what I need   \usepackage[bibstyle=historian,citestyle=authoryear-comp,natbib,sorting=nty,babel=hyphen,printseries]{biblatex}

Answer (score 6):

I'm the author of the original SBL LaTeX BibTeX styles. This is no longer supported.

But for those who find this thread in google, you might be interested in a completely new implementation covering SBLHS 2nd ed. done in BibLaTeX.

See https://github.com/dcpurton/biblatex-sbl for source and issue tracker.

It's also available in [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-sbl) and in TeXLive and MiKTeX.

It's much more flexible and robust than the BibTeX implementation, and much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this page: http://wiki.marshwiggle.net/doku.php?id=sbllatex:main There are many examples including some classes and packages dedicated to this kind of style.

You can find the corresponding `.bst` file here: http://svn.marshwiggle.net/sbllatex/trunk/bst/sbl.bst

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't even get their example files to compile without errors. I am using MikTeX on Windows and I think these files might assume TeXLive. In any case, right now the site has completely disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

The same people who used to publish the MarshWiggle website have started another with a more robust SBL Latex style. I have been using this for quite a while with very good results. I made a few changes to the essay style to suit my needs, but the BST is very good.

https://launchpad.net/sbllatex

Comment: The link is about a 'traditional' BibTeX style, not one for `biblatex`.

Comment: You know, I never new there was a difference...

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's interest I have maintained Robet Fischer's SBL-paper and am porting biblatex-chicago which I hope to have on CTAN soon. Contact me for more info.

Note: I just found https://github.com/dcpurton/biblatex-sbl/blob/master/README.md

I couldn't tell you just yet how different or similar this is to mine.