# Choose a bibstyle

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Which bibstyle would be the best for following requirements?

(`abbrv` or another one?)

I am aware about the possibility of a manual modification at the end, but maybe a bibstyle for this assignment (tex template of a conference) would be available.

Requirements:

```
\item {\bf References:} Must be numbered in the order cited in the manuscript
and indicated in the text by a number in square brackets ({\it e.g.}, [1]).\newline
\newline
The required format for references is:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item {\bf Papers:}
    Author, paper title, {\em journal name (in italics)}, volume and issue
    numbers, year, inclusive pages. {\it e.g.}: \smallskip \newline
    [1] T.C. Hsia, Simple robust schemes for space control
    of robot manipulators, {\it Int. J. of Robotics and Automation}, 9(4),
    1994, 167-174.
    \item {\bf Books:} Author, {\em title (in italics)} (location of
    publisher, publisher, year). {\it e.g.}:\smallskip \newline
    [2] M. Kayston and W.R. Fried, {\it Avionic Navigation
    Systems} (New York: John Wiley and Sons Inc., 1969).
    \item {\bf Chapters in Books:} Chapter Author, Chapter Title, in
    Editor (Ed.), {\em title (in italics)}  (location of publisher,
    publisher, year) inclusive pages. {\it e.g.}: \smallskip \newline
    [3] P.O. Biship, Neurophysiology of binocular vision,
    in J. Housman (Ed.) {\em Handbook of physiology}, 4 (New York:
    Springer-Verlag, 1970) 342-366.
    \item {\bf Proceedings Papers:} Author, paper title, {\em proceedings
    title (in italics)}, City, Country, year, inclusive pages. {\it e.g.}:
    \smallskip \newline
    [4] W.J. Book, Modelling design and control of
    flexible manipulator arms: A tutorial review, {\it Proc. 29th IEEE Conf. on
    Decision and Control}, San Francisco, USA, 1990, 500-506.
    \end{itemize}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

`makebst` allows you to create your own `bibtex` style. All one has to do is open a terminal window (command line interface), type

```
latex makebst
```

and answer the questions at the prompt. At the end it generates a style with your specifications.

Comment: rather cool. tried it. tnx. maybe i will focus on that later - modifications on bst would be necessary, but then i would maybe prefer to work on an abbrv alternative. have to finish tex code itself currently due to a deadline.

Comment: @Monkey The alternative would be to use `biblatex`. If one is familiar with LaTeX it might be easier than the reverse polish notation used in `.bst`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to consider the following solution using `biblatex`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mwe.bib}
    @article{Test1,
    author = {An Author},
    title = {Nice title},
    journaltitle = {The Journal of Nonsense},
    date = {2012},
    volume = {1},
    number = {13},
    pages = {13-23},
    }

    @book{Test2,
    author = {Big Bethor},
    title = {Some random Book},
    date = {1999},
    publisher = {Oneandonly Publishing},
    location = {Earth},
    pages = {18-22},
    }

    @inbook{Test3,
    author = {Crazy Cethor and Dumb Dethor},
    title = {Any weird title},
    booktitle = {The book of stuff},
    date = {1857},
    editor = {Edwin Editor},
    publisher = {Crazy Publishers},
    location = {The Universe},
    pages = {899-947},
    }
    @inproceedings{Test4,
    author = {Frank Fauthor and Gary Gethor},
    editor = {Oscar Odithor},
    title = {My Research},
    booktitle = {The Conference of Research},
    date = {2030},
    venue = {Vaduz, Liechtenstein},
    pages = {255-256},
    }

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,
    sorting=none,
    firstinits=true,
    backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\begin{document}
\blindtext \cite{Test2} \blindtext \cite{Test1,Test4} \blindtext \cite{Test3}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

There are some minor formatting things to optimize

- remove the quotes around article, inbook and inproceedings titles
- remove the brackets around the location in inproceedings
- change the "ed. by" to "(Ed.)" (this is already partly adressed in [Customizing biblatex styles using \usebibmacro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75837/customizing-biblatex-styles-using-usebibmacro))

but these should be quite easy to do. The key requirements (citation in square brackets, numbering according to citation order) is fulfilled as far as I can see.