# Biblatex Compile Issue

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` (`parencite{}` or `textcite{}`) and in the final pdf appaer unusual issues.

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,ibidtracker=false,maxbibnames=100,maxcitenames=3,hyperref=true,backend=biber,isbn=false,sorting=ynt,sortcites=true,labelalpha,maxalphanames=1,doi=false,dashed=false,urldate=long,block=space]{biblatex}
```

For example, in some cases, the first name shows up.

> (Robinson 2009; A. Chen et al. 2011).

or even if I give a maximum cite names (3) some authors show up in this way:

> (Jendritzky, Bucher, Laschewski, Schultz et al. 1998)

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% % % % % % % Biblio % % % % % % % % % %
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,ibidtracker=false,maxbibnames=100,maxcitenames=3,hyperref=true,backend=biber,isbn=false,sorting=ynt,sortcites=true,labelalpha,maxalphanames=1,doi=false,dashed=false,urldate=long,block=space]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameFormat{lastname}{#1\addspace}
\DeclareNameFormat{last-init}{#1 #4\addspace}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{lastname}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{lastname}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-init}

\DeclareSortingScheme{last}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{author}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{title}
    \field{year}
  }
}

\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
      \map{
        \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{(.+)\sand}, final]
        \step[fieldset=sortname, fieldvalue=$1, final]  }
}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \ifentrytype{misc}
    {}
      {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
       {}
         {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
           \printfield{labelyear}%
            \printfield{extrayear}}}}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{%
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
}

\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

% % % % % % % % %
% Commas as separators
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{} %quita coma entre apellido y nombre

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}%quitar pag.

% Comma before and after journal volume
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
  \printfield{volume}%
%  \setunit*{\adddot}% DELETED
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

% Issue/date macros removed after journal number
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
%  \setunit{\addspace}% DELETED
%  \usebibmacro{issue+date}% DELETED
%  \setunit{\addcolon\space}% DELETED
%  \usebibmacro{issue}% DELETED
  \newunit}

% "In:" removed for articles; issue/date macros added after note+pages macro
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
%  \usebibmacro{in:}% DELETED
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \setunit{\addspace}% NEW
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}% NEW
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}% NEW
  \usebibmacro{issue}% NEW
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}




\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Chen2011,
  Title                    = {Developmental Neurotoxicants in E-Waste: An Emerging Health Concern},
  Author                   = {Chen, A. and Dietrich, K. N. and Huo, A. and Ho, S.-M.},
  Journal                  = {Environmental Health Perspectives},
  Year                     = {2011},
  Pages                    = {431-438},
  Volume                   = {119},

  Owner                    = {Admin},
  Timestamp                = {2014.05.20}
}

\end{filecontents}



\begin{document}

\parencite{Chen2011}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give us more information ([MWE](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html)) to reproduce the behaviour you are describing.

Comment: The minexample works fine....

Comment: So it doesn't show what you have been describing?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. It is probably the compiling process. But I repeated it several times.

Comment: Does that mean the problem is gone?

Comment: This is most likely caused by `biblatex`'s disambiguation facilities. If there are several authors (different authors that is - by a `biblatex` standard, so "J. Smith" `\neq` "Jane Smith" even if the two might be the same) with the same last name, `biblatex` adds a name initial to disambiguate them. The same goes for long lists of co-authors (more names are displayed to disambiguate). The issue does not occur in the MWE as there is no need of disambiguation.

Comment: See [firstnames appear erratically](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864) for example. There relevant options you need to investigate are `uniquename` and `uniquelist` (see pp. 186-187, 232-236 and 59-60 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)). In short `uniquename=false` and `uniquelist=false` might give what you expect, but this may not be the best result in overall terms.

Comment: Thank you very much! uniquename=false and uniquelist=false give me what I expect.

Comment: @moewe Want to write up an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B I'd rather close it as a duplicate of [Literature with Biber generates strange citations: firstnames appear erratically](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864).