# One of my cites shows with first name initial for some reason?

Tags: biblatex

My cites are showing Surname, year as expected.. Except this one:

```
@article{wang2013genome,

  title={Genome-wide transcript analysis of early maize leaf development reveals gene cohorts associated with the differentiation of C4 Kranz anatomy},

  author={Wang, Peng and Kelly, Steven and Fouracre, Jim P. and Langdale, Jane A.},

  journal={The Plant Journal},

  volume={75},

  number={4},

  pages={656--670},

  year={2013},

  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

That shows as "(P. Wang et al. 2013)" instead of "(Wang et al. 2013)".

I have noticed that if I change the name from Wang to Aang it correctly prints "(Aang et al. 2013)". But that's obviously not the correct name. What is happening and how can I fix it?

This is what I am using:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,bibstyle=authoryear,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=2,firstinits=true,uniquename=init,uniquelist=minyear]{biblatex}
```

Comment: I bet you have more than one Wang, `biblatex` adds the initial to make the cite unique. So you can say, it is *this* wang that published the article, not *that* wang.

Comment: Welcome! You have `uniquename=init` which tells Biblatex to use the initial to ensure labels are unique when required. If you don't want that, tell it to use another method. (Or tell it not to worry about unique labels - but that's really not a good idea.)

Comment: See also [biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864), [Literature with Biber generates strange citations: firstnames appear erratically](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864) and p. 59 of the [`biblatex` doc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for a full list of possible options for `uniquename` as well as pp. 234-236 §4.11.4 *Name Disambiguation* for examples.