# Biblatex: first names in text only for some sources - why?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I have a rather complex document using the biblatex style apa. For some sources that I cite first names appear (which I don't want, according to the APA guidelines), such as in:

```
\autocite{windttheoryconsciousness}
```

which yields

```
(Jennifer M. Windt & Noreika, 2011)
```

However

```
\autocite{stumbrysinductionreview}
```

yields

```
(Stumbrys, Erlacher, Schädlich, & Schredl, 2012)
```

These are the entries in the .bib file:

```
@article{windttheoryconsciousness,
title={How to integrate dreaming into a general theory of consciousness—a critical review of existing positions and suggestions for future research},
author={Jennifer M. Windt and Valdas Noreika},
journal={Consciousness and cognition},
volume={20},
number={4},
pages={1091--1107},
year=2011,
publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{stumbrysinductionreview,
title={Induction of lucid dreams: A systematic review of evidence},
author={Tadas Stumbrys and Daniel Erlacher and Melanie Sch{\"a}dlich and Michael Schredl},
journal={Consciousness and Cognition},
volume={21},
number={3},
pages={1456--1475},
year=2012,
publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

I tried a minimal example, but I could not reproduce the problem (which was that first names sometimes appear and sometimes not). Therefore I can phrase my question only vaguely: What could be the difference between these sources? I noticed that sometimes the year tag was in curly brackets, but I removed them and recompiled -- still the same result in the complex document. Also, for some sources in the bib file I noticed that authors were separated by commas instead of and. Changed that and recompiled -- still the same. Both of these sources appeared for the first time in the document.

I'd appreciate any guide in solving this problem.

Comment: You need to enter names in the `.bib` file as `Surname, FirstName(s)`. The problem lies in "Jennifer M. Windt" which is treated as a multiword last name.

Comment: You have an other source where the author has the same surname (Windt) with another first name.

Comment: See also [biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864), [Literature with Biber generates strange citations: firstnames appear erratically](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864). (Technically, the first could even be a duplicate.)

Comment: BTW: I believe that name disambiguation is part of APA style. Though I seem to remember there were some changes to that recently in `biblatex-apa` (not sure if the version with these changes has already been released).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If two different authors have the same surname, `biblatex` adds the first name to identify each of them. (You may add the `uniquename=false` option to change this behavior.)

Ex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{windttheoryconsciousness,
title={How to integrate dreaming into a general theory of consciousness—a critical review of existing positions and suggestions for future research},
author={Jennifer M. Windt and Valdas Noreika},
journal={Consciousness and cognition},
volume={20},
number={4},
pages={1091--1107},
year=2011,
publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{windttheoryconsciousness2,
title={How to integrate dreaming into a general theory of consciousness—a critical review of existing positions and suggestions for future research},
author={Alex Windt and Valdas Noreika},
journal={Consciousness and cognition},
volume={20},
number={4},
pages={1091--1107},
year=2011,
publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{stumbrysinductionreview,
title={Induction of lucid dreams: A systematic review of evidence},
author={Tadas Stumbrys and Daniel Erlacher and Melanie Sch{\"a}dlich and Michael Schredl},
journal={Consciousness and Cognition},
volume={21},
number={3},
pages={1456--1475},
year=2012,
publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite{windttheoryconsciousness}
\autocite{windttheoryconsciousness2}
\autocite{stumbrysinductionreview}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]