# Analagous references with different in-text-citation styles

Tags: biblatex, author

I have the following two analogous references

```
@article{ref1,
  author = {Martí, R. and Laguna, M. and Glover, F. and Campos, V.},
  journal = {European Journal},
  number = 2,
  pages = {450-459},
  title = {yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy},
  volume = 135,
  year = 2001
}
@article{ref2,
  author = {Lim, A. and Lin, J. and Rodrigues, B. and Xiao, F.},
  journal = {Journal},
  number = 2,
  pages = {180-188},
  title = {xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx},
  volume = 6,
  year = {2006}
}
```

When I make an in-text-citation, I get a different output style for them:

```
(Martí et al. 2001)
(Lim; J. Lin; B. Rodrigues, et al. 2006)
```

I'd like to get the same citation style as produced with reference `ref1`.

I'm using `biblatex` package with some parameters

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
```

The following are additional configurations of the template I'm using

```
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}
\addbibresource{thesis.bib}
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
```

Another reference of another work of "Lim, A." is

```
@article{ref3,
    author="Lim, A. and Lin, J. and Xiao, F.",
    title="zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
    journal="Applied Intelligence",
    year="2007",
    volume="26",
    number="3",
    pages="175--182"
}
```

Comment: I get 'Martí et al. 2001' and 'Lim et al. 2006' as I would expect. Please prepare a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). We need to see a full working example to see what is going on. Also check the `.log` and `.blg` files for warnings and errors. It would also be nice if you could show a screenshot of the output you get.

Comment: Your second style is rather odd: You're missing Lim's initial, and the semicoons are strange (especially with the comma before *et al.*)  Are you using an unusual class of some sort?

Comment: I second moewe's request for a MWE(B). But, a guess thus far: do you have other citations of another work by "Lim, A."?

Comment: I have tried to use these references in a new blank project. I've got 'Martí et al. 2001' and 'Lim et al. 2006' like moewe. So, I think the problem is the template I'm using. I'm going to add the additional configurations the template uses. Maybe it helps to identify the problem.

Comment: Please consider my question in your analysis of the issue. It is a (configurable) feature of `biblatex` to disambiguate entries. So if you have two or more references by "Lim, A." (in 2006?) it is possibly the reason why more names are given.

Comment: With a current version of `biblatex` `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` and `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}` as well as `\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}` are preferable.

Comment: Yes, I have another reference to another work of "Lim, A", but the year is 2007. I'm going to add this reference in my post.

Comment: gusbrs' guess is the best we can do with what you have given us. If you have several Lins and Rodrigues' you get initials. If you have more citations with Lim you might get to see more names than just 'Lim' alone. You need to check out the `uniquename` and `uniquelist` options.

Comment: So, when you try the three of them together in a blank project, what do you get?

Comment: See also [biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864), [Literature with Biber generates strange citations: firstnames appear erratically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864), [Biblatex: first names in text only for some sources - why?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321460/35864)

Comment: In a new blank project, I get: "Martí et al. 2001", "Lim; Lin; Rodrigues, et al. 2006", and "Lim is Lim; Lin; Xiao 2007". So, a similar problem appears in a new blank project. But I don't know how to solve it :(

Comment: Have you read my links? Use `uniquelist=false` and `uniquename=false`.

Comment: It less a problem than a feature. `biblatex` does this in order to assure you won't get ambiguous citations. But, of course, you might not want this behavior (even knowing why it happens). To change it, moewe's links and comments are the way to go.

Comment: Thank you!!! It works!! Now, how is the best way to close this post? Should I post the answer?