# Author-year Citation Issue

Tags: biblatex, citing, authoryear

I have this @book item in my bib file (I'm using Biblatex):

```
@book{series2009microgrids,
  author={Chowdhury, S. and Chowdhury, S. P. and Crossley, P.},
  title={Microgrids and active distribution networks},
  publisher={IET Renewable Energy Series 6},
  isbn={978-1-84919-014-5},
  year={2009},
}
```

Using `\parencite{series2009microgrids}` to cite this in my text, it shows as
**(S. Chowdhury, S. P. Chowdhury e Crossley, 2009)**. The first author was supposed to be just **Chowdhury**, not **S. Chowdhury,** and the same for the second author. Does anyone knows why is this happening?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

That is due to biblatex trying to uniquely identify all authors. You have two authors with the same last name, so the initial of the first name is used as an additional identifier. You can disable this with `uniquename=false`. See [Biblatex: first names in text only for some sources - why?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321460/biblatex-first-names-in-text-only-for-some-sources-why)

Comment: Oh, nice. Thank you for the answer