# Adjust biber style

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biblatex with biber for my bibliography. At the moment I'M stuck at a point where it is getting really deep into latex. I have the following Styles, that I need to implement:

For Book:

> name, g.; name2 , g2.: title. subtitle. edition location Year.
>
> Becker, J.; Rosemann, M.: Logistik und CIM. Die effiziente Material- und Informations-flußgestaltung in Industrieunternehmen. 2. Aufl. Berlin 1993.

For Article:

> name, g.: title. In: journal, volume (year) number, pages
>
> Becker, J.; Rosemann, M.; Schütte, R.: Grundsätze ordnungsgemäßer Modellierung 
>   (GoM). In: Wirtschaftsinformatik, 37 (1995) 4, S. 435-445.

For Misc (online source):

> name, g.: title. year. url. retrievingdate.
>
> Kargermann, H.: Accounting as a Management Tool. 1995. http://www.sap.com/events/event4.htm. Abrufdatum 1996-02-12.

My current output looks like:
Book: [image: book]
Article: [image: article]
Misc: [image: misc]

Here is the code:
https://www.overleaf.com/8433813pqyccbpgnmtc

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    numbers=noenddot, 
    listof=entryprefix,
    captions=nooneline
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 

%Literatur
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear, maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=3,doi=false, isbn=false]{biblatex} 

\addbibresource{Thesis.bib}

%% ; zwischen Autoren/Editoren in Bib
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{; }
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{; }
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%et al. anstatt u. a.
    andothers = {et al.},
}


% Einzug der 2. Zeile im Literatuverzeichnis 
\setlength\bibhang{1.5cm}

%Abrufdatum
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{% 
    urlseen = {Abrufdatum }, 
}

%Runde Klammern um Jahreszahl in den Fußnoten
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperrefparens}{\bibhyperref{\mkbibparens{#1}}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}%
    {\printtext[bibhyperrefparens]{%
            \printfield[]{labelyear}%
            \printfield[]{extrayear}%
        }%
    }%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Thesis.bib}

@article{Zhong.2006,
    author = {Zhong, Chen-Bo and Liljenquist, Katie},
    year = {2006},
    title = {Washing Away Your Sins: Threatened Morality and Physical Cleansing},
    pages = {1451--1452},
    volume = {313},
    number = {5792},
    journal = {Science}
}

@book{Zikmund.2003,
    author = {Zikmund, William G.},
    year = {2003},
    title = {Business research methods},
    edition = {7. Aufl.},
    loacation = {Berlin},
    publisher = {Thomson/South-Western}
}

@misc{Thommen.2016,
    author = {Thommen, Jean-Paul and Siepermann, Markus},
    editor = {{Springer Gabler Verlag}},
    year = {2016},
    title = {Gabler Wirtschaftslexikon: Stichwort: Heuristik},
    url = {http://wirtschaftslexikon.gabler.de/Archiv/4969/heuristik-v8.html}
}



\end{filecontents} 

\begin{document}
article\footcite[Vgl.][S. 1 f.]{Zhong.2006} \\
book\footcite[Vgl.][S. 1 f.]{Zikmund.2003} \\
misc\footcite[Vgl.][S. 1 f.]{Thommen.2016}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you just move your MWE to the question here? How should your citations look like? Does your desired output include no italics/quotation marks? What about the sorting?

Comment: Sorry, thougt it would be easier on overleavf. Someone already edited my post.

Comment: Note that your `.bib` file is responsible for some of the output you get. You should have `edition = {7}` instead of `7 ed.`. And your are missing the location in your `@book` entry.

Comment: It would also be more helpful if you could show us the exact output you expect with your example citations and not some generic output. Your `@misc` for example has an `editor` which your desired output has not. What do we do about it?

Comment: Ok changed it. I thinks some entries have more information than needed. But this should be not a problem since you define the output for the bibliography, right? My only problem is, how I can define the output. I googled it but cannot understand that complicated code.

Comment: Well, the question is: Do you want to incorporate the additional information in some way, or do you want to rigorously ignore it?

Comment: I want to ignore the additional information. I collected the ressources with citavi and exported it to my bib file. So i just want to define the output in the bibliography like I described it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this. Please note also the changes I have applied to your `.bib` file as well as your cite commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, bibstyle=authortitle, sorting=nyt, maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=3, doi=false, isbn=false, giveninits=true, uniquename=init, alldates=ymd, datezeros=true]{biblatex} 

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%et al. anstatt u. a.
  andothers = {et al.},
}

\setlength\bibhang{1.5cm}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{% 
  urlseen = {Abrufdatum}, 
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \usebibmacro{url}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \usebibmacro{urldate}}}

%Runde Klammern um Jahreszahl in den Fußnoten
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperrefparens}{\bibhyperref{\mkbibparens{#1}}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}%
    {\printtext[bibhyperrefparens]{%
       \printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{\usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location+date}{publisher}}
\renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{\usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location+date}{institution}}
\renewbibmacro*{organization+location+date}{\usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location+date}{organization}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Zhong.2006,
  author = {Zhong, Chen-Bo and Liljenquist, Katie},
  year = {2006},
  title = {Washing Away Your Sins: Threatened Morality and Physical Cleansing},
  pages = {1451--1452},
  volume = {313},
  number = {5792},
  journal = {Science},
}

@book{Zikmund.2003,
  author = {Zikmund, William G.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Business research methods},
  edition = {7},
  publisher = {Thomson/South-Western},
  location = {Berlin},
}

@misc{Thommen.2016,
  author = {Thommen, Jean-Paul and Siepermann, Markus},
  year = {2016},
  title = {Gabler Wirtschaftslexikon: Stichwort: Heuristik},
  url = {http://wirtschaftslexikon.gabler.de/Archiv/4969/heuristik-v8.html},
  urldate = {1996-12-05},
}
\end{filecontents} 

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
article\footcite[Vgl.][1\psq]{Zhong.2006} \\
book\footcite[Vgl.][1\psq]{Zikmund.2003} \\
misc\footcite[Vgl.][1\psq]{Thommen.2016}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: whoops deleted my old post. okay maybe it because you use the documentclass article. i will test it

Comment: @GR_ The documentclass should have no bearing on `biblatex`'s output. I get only the last name and year in citations with my MWE. What do you get with the exact code I posted?

Comment: I tried it with the overleaf explorer. The output there is the correct one. In my local installation of latex it displays "name, givenname (year)". I think it is a problem in my own file.

Comment: @GR_ Maybe your system is outdated. Make an update of `biblatex` and Biber.

Comment: oh I see the problem. This case only appears if the name f.e. "Wood" ist defined for different persons. So if there is a "Wood, J." and a "Wood, G." it displays the name and the short givenname for every cite (f.e. "Wood, G. (2014)"). Is there a way to remove the givenname anyway?

Comment: @GR_ `uniquename=false` instead of `init`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864

Comment: Yes it works, thanks! One last issue and its perfect :). In the footnote: If there are more than 3 authors it should only display one author and et. al. But in the moment it displays two authors and et. al. Is there away to fix this?

Comment: @GR_ Mhhh, maybe you have a `uniquelist` problem this time. Try `uniquelist=false` http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864

Comment: I mentioned there are some minor things that needs to be fixed. Maybe you can answer them in the other topic, since you are familiar with the code :) --> http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356799/biblatex-minor-adjustments-in-bibliography