# Biblatex minor adjustments in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I need to change some minor things in my bibliography. I'm using biblatex with biber.

1. *[done]* How can I change the bibliography to be displayed in "\normalfont"? At the moment the title/subtitle/publisher/journal are in italic style and the url have a different style.
2. *[done]* How can I add a colon after the author in every documenttype
3. *[done]* Remove quotation marks around title in documenttype @article
4. *[done]* In documenttype @article and @book add a "." between titel and subtitle "title. subtitle."

:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, bibstyle=authortitle, sorting=nyt, maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=3, doi=false, isbn=false, giveninits=true, uniquename=init, datezeros=true, urldate=iso8601, date=iso8601]{biblatex} 

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%et al. anstatt u. a.
andothers = {et al.},
}

\setlength\bibhang{1.5cm}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{% 
urlseen = {Abrufdatum}, 
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
\usebibmacro{url}%
\iffieldundef{urlyear}
{}
{\newunit
\usebibmacro{urldate}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperrefparens}{\bibhyperref{\mkbibparens{#1}}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
\iffieldundef{labelyear}
{}%
{\printtext[bibhyperrefparens]{%
\printfield{labelyear}%
\printfield{extrayear}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
\usebibmacro{journal}%
\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
\iffieldundef{series}
{}
{\newunit
\printfield{series}%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}}%
\printfield{volume}%
\setunit{\addspace}%
\usebibmacro{issue+date}%
\setunit{\addcolon\space}%
\usebibmacro{issue}%
\setunit{\addspace}%
\printfield{number}%
\newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
\printlist{location}%
\setunit{\addspace}%
\usebibmacro{date}%
\newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{\usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location+date}{publisher}}
\renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{\usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location+date}{institution}}
\renewbibmacro*{organization+location+date}{\usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location+date}{organization}}


\DeclareFieldFormat [article] {journaltitle}{\normalfont{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat [book] {title}{\normalfont{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat [misc] {title}{\normalfont{#1}} \appto{\biburlsetup}{\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\normalfont}}

\DeclareFieldFormat [book] {title}{\normalfont{#1}} \renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat [article] {title}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat [article] {title}{#1}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Zhong.2006,
author = {Zhong, Chen-Bo and Liljenquist, Katie},
year = {2006},
title = {Washing Away Your Sins: Threatened Morality and Physical Cleansing},
pages = {1451--1452},
volume = {313},
number = {5792},
journal = {Science},
}

@book{Zikmund.2003,
author = {Zikmund, William G.},
year = {2003},
title = {Business research methods},
edition = {7},
publisher = {Thomson/South-Western},
location = {Berlin},
}

@misc{Thommen.2016,
author = {Thommen, Jean-Paul and Siepermann, Markus},
year = {2016},
title = {Gabler Wirtschaftslexikon: Stichwort: Heuristik},
url = {http://wirtschaftslexikon.gabler.de/Archiv/4969/heuristik-v8.html},
urldate = {1996-12-05},
}
\end{filecontents} 

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
article\footcite[Vgl.][1\psq]{Zhong.2006} \\
book\footcite[Vgl.][1\psq]{Zikmund.2003} \\
misc\footcite[Vgl.][1\psq]{Thommen.2016}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/8442810jqhmvxrsjmwb

Thank you!

Comment: For point 4, you have   a dot by default.

Comment: Yes but the problem is, that the colon is defined for the case there is a subtitle. I need to change this special case. --> [title. subtitle.] vs. [title: subtitle]

Comment: But I've just tested, adding a subtitle, and I do obtain dot. Your example code had no subtitles.

Comment: Check you haven't redefined `\subtitlepunct` somewhere (you probably haven't). But you will need to change your bib entries. You have the title field manually set as `title = {Washing Away Your Sins: Threatened Morality and Physical Cleansing}`. You have to separate them out: `title = {Washing Away Your Sins}, subtitle = {Threatened Morality and Physical Cleansing}`

Comment: `\normalfont` is overkill. `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{#1}` is enough. You can combine the format for several types into one `\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,book,misc]{title}{#1}`. If you want this for *all* entry types, go with `\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}`. (Note that your code gets harder to read if you drop the indentation.)

Comment: I'm sorry guys. You are absolutely right. It was an export format fault with citavi. Now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could fix point 1, 2, 3 with the following commands:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat
[article]
{journaltitle}{\normalfont{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat
[book]
{title}{\normalfont{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat
[misc]
{title}{\normalfont{#1}}
\appto{\biburlsetup}{\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\normalfont}}

\DeclareFieldFormat
[book]
{title}{\normalfont{#1}}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat
[article]
{title}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat
[article]
{title}{#1}
```

4. You can export the title in the right format with citavi

All solved :) Thank you guys.

Comment: Please have a look at my suggestions below your question regarding your `\DeclareFieldFormat`s. BTW: You may want to remove the edit with the solution from your question, so content does not duplicate.