# Cite only first author surname with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm trying to use ShareLatex with `biblatex` citing package, however, I'm not able to produce the citing using only the first author surname in the citations.

The minimal example is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Cid-Fernandes+05,
   author = {{Cid Fernandes}, R. and {Mateus}, A. and {Sodr{\'e}}, L. and 
    {Stasi{\'n}ska}, G. and {Gomes}, J.~M.},
    title = "{Semi-empirical analysis of Sloan Digital Sky Survey galaxies - I. Spectral synthesis method}",
  journal = {\mnras},
   eprint = {astro-ph/0412481},
 keywords = {galaxies: evolution, galaxies: fundamental parameters, galaxies: statistics, galaxies: stellar content},
     year = 2005,
    month = apr,
   volume = 358,
    pages = {363-378},
      doi = {10.1111/j.1365-2966.2005.08752.x},
   adsurl = {},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{Davies+07,
   author = {{Davies}, R.~I. and {M{\"u}ller S{\'a}nchez}, F. and {Genzel}, R. and 
    {Tacconi}, L.~J. and {Hicks}, E.~K.~S. and {Friedrich}, S. and 
    {Sternberg}, A.},
    title = "{A Close Look at Star Formation around Active Galactic Nuclei}",
  journal = {\apj},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {0704.1374},
 keywords = {Galaxies: Active, Galaxies: Nuclei, Galaxies: Seyfert, Galaxies: Starburst, Infrared: Galaxies},
     year = 2007,
    month = dec,
   volume = 671,
    pages = {1388-1412},
      doi = {10.1086/523032},
   adsurl = {},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{Davies+09,
   author = {{Davies}, R.~I. and {Maciejewski}, W. and {Hicks}, E.~K.~S. and 
    {Tacconi}, L.~J. and {Genzel}, R. and {Engel}, H.},
    title = "{Stellar and Molecular Gas Kinematics Of NGC 1097: Inflow Driven by a Nuclear Spiral}",
  journal = {\apj},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {0903.0313},
 keywords = {galaxies: active, galaxies: individual: NGC 1097, galaxies: kinematics and dynamics, galaxies: nuclei, galaxies: spiral, infrared: galaxies},
     year = 2009,
    month = sep,
   volume = 702,
    pages = {114-128},
      doi = {10.1088/0004-637X/702/1/114},
   adsurl = {},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{Riffel-Rogerio+09,
   author = {{Riffel}, R. and {Pastoriza}, M.~G. and {Rodr{\'{\i}}guez-Ardila}, A. and 
    {Bonatto}, C.},
    title = "{Probing the near-infrared stellar population of Seyfert galaxies}",
  journal = {\mnras},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {0907.4144},
 primaryClass = "astro-ph.CO",
 keywords = {stars: AGB and post-AGB , circumstellar matter , infrared: stars},
     year = 2009,
    month = nov,
   volume = 400,
    pages = {273-290},
      doi = {10.1111/j.1365-2966.2009.15448.x},
   adsurl = {},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{Riffel-Rogerio+11a,
   author = {{Riffel}, R. and {Riffel}, R.~A. and {Ferrari}, F. and {Storchi-Bergmann}, T.
    },
    title = "{Intermediate-age stars as the origin of low stellar velocity dispersion nuclear rings: the case of Mrk 1157}",
  journal = {\mnras},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {1105.2487},
 keywords = {methods: data analysis, galaxies: individual: Mrk 1157, galaxies: individual: NGC 591, galaxies: Seyfert, galaxies: stellar content},
     year = 2011,
    month = sep,
   volume = 416,
    pages = {493-500},
      doi = {10.1111/j.1365-2966.2011.19061.x},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011MNRAS.416..493R},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{Riffel-Rogemar+10a,
   author = {{Riffel}, R. and {Storchi-Bergmann}, T. and {Riffel}, R. and 
    {Pastoriza}, M.~G.},
    title = "{Intermediate-age Stars as Origin of the Low-velocity Dispersion Nuclear Ring in Mrk 1066}",
  journal = {\apj},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {1002.2534},
 keywords = {galaxies: individual: Mrk 1066, galaxies: nuclei, galaxies: Seyfert, galaxies: stellar content, infrared: galaxies},
     year = 2010,
    month = apr,
   volume = 713,
    pages = {469-474},
      doi = {10.1088/0004-637X/713/1/469},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010ApJ...713..469R},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp,citestyle=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{issn} % Remove issn
  \clearfield{doi} % Remove doi
  \clearfield{eprint} % Remove ARCHIVE
  \clearfield{title} % Remove title
  \ifentrytype{online}{}{% Remove url except for @online

    \clearfield{url}
  }
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\title{Test}
\author{}
\date{April 2017}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

This citation sequence should appear in the text as  (Cid-Fernandes et al. 2005, Davies et al. 2007,2009, Riffel et al., 2009, 2010,2011) {\bf and not as it actually appears}  \parencite{Cid-Fernandes+05,Davies+07,Davies+09, Riffel-Rogerio+09,Riffel-Rogerio+11a,Riffel-Rogemar+10a} 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The citation sequence should appear in the text as

> (Cid-Fernandes et al.  2005,Davies et al.  2007,2009, Riffel et al., 2009, 2010,2011)

Which is the default style in astronomy publications, as MNRAS and ApJ, for example.

and not as it actually appears (the default style of bibtex)

> (Cid Fernandes et al. 2005; Davies, Maciejewski, et al. 2009; Davies, Muller Sanchez, et al. 2007; R. A. Riffel et al. 2010; R. Riffel, Pastoriza, et al. 2009; R. Riffel, R. A. Riffel, et al. 2011)

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It looks like what you get is correct, for the cited authors are different and if only "Riffel et al." was given you would get an ambiguous citation. This is `biblatex`'s default behavior for the case, but can probably be reconfigured. In any case, you should not supply your code as a link, but rather include it here in your question, as a a [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/105447).

Comment: Rogério, I meant for you to include the MWEB in the question, which you can edit. The comments are indeed not appropriate for this. Even if you already received what's likely the answer you are looking for, please do so, so others can later access the relevant information to the question (the link you provided will probably not last long).

Comment: See [Set limit to one author when using “et al.” in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864), [biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864) and [Literature with Biber generates strange citations: firstnames appear erratically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864)

Answer (score 4):

The number of names shown in citations and the bibliography is determined by the package options `maxnames`, `minnames`, `maxbibnames`, `minbibnames`, `maxcitenames`, and `mincitenames`.

Use the first two if you want the citation and bibliography name lists to be the same; use the `bib` and `cite` versions if have differing requirements for citations and the bibliography.

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,maxnames=1]{biblatex}
```

But `biblatex` also tries to disambiguate name lists where possible, and this will override the `maxnames` value if there are two papers with identical first authors but different second author for example. This is controlled by the `uniquelist` option.  So for your case you need:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,maxnames=1,uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
```

Comment: I don't think that's the OP's problem, look at the citations, they are of different groups of authors. That's why they are not merged, probably. The first citation gives one author plus "et al.". Likely, what is required is `uniquename=false`, if the OP really wants the result, after due explanation.

Comment: @gusbrs Yes, I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. However, it is still not solving the R. Riffel and R. A. Riffel citations, Any way to solve this?

Comment: @RogérioRiffel As mentioned in the comments on your question, now you should make a minimal working document which includes the two (and only the two) bib items that show the problem and edit your question to add that. Links to Sharelatex are not acceptable.

Comment: @AlanMunn I tryed to edit the question, but I was not able to use the code formating, I don't know why. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

As Alan Munn suggested, in order to obtain the desired results you should load `biblatex` with options:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,maxnames=1,uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
```

The remaining problem with the references you mentioned are due to your `.bib` file, for the names you wish to see merged are different between, on the one side, the entries `Riffel-Rogerio+07` and `Riffel-Rogerio+06` which state "{Riffel}, R." and, on the other, the entry `Riffel-Rogemar+10a` wich says "{Riffel}, R.~A.". `biblatex` has no way to know if this is the same person, given the different names. Supposing it is, you can remove the "A." from `Riffel-Rogemar+10a` to obtain what you want (or add the "A." on the others).

Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Cid-Fernandes+05,
   author = {{Cid Fernandes}, R. and {Mateus}, A. and {Sodr{\'e}}, L. and 
    {Stasi{\'n}ska}, G. and {Gomes}, J.~M.},
    title = "{Semi-empirical analysis of Sloan Digital Sky Survey galaxies - I. Spectral synthesis method}",
  journal = {\mnras},
   eprint = {astro-ph/0412481},
 keywords = {galaxies: evolution, galaxies: fundamental parameters, galaxies: statistics, galaxies: stellar content},
     year = 2005,
    month = apr,
   volume = 358,
    pages = {363-378},
      doi = {10.1111/j.1365-2966.2005.08752.x},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2005MNRAS.358..363C},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{Davies+07,
   author = {{Davies}, R.~I. and {M{\"u}ller S{\'a}nchez}, F. and {Genzel}, R. and 
    {Tacconi}, L.~J. and {Hicks}, E.~K.~S. and {Friedrich}, S. and 
    {Sternberg}, A.},
    title = "{A Close Look at Star Formation around Active Galactic Nuclei}",
  journal = {\apj},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {0704.1374},
 keywords = {Galaxies: Active, Galaxies: Nuclei, Galaxies: Seyfert, Galaxies: Starburst, Infrared: Galaxies},
     year = 2007,
    month = dec,
   volume = 671,
    pages = {1388-1412},
      doi = {10.1086/523032},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2007ApJ...671.1388D},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{Davies+09,
   author = {{Davies}, R.~I. and {Maciejewski}, W. and {Hicks}, E.~K.~S. and 
    {Tacconi}, L.~J. and {Genzel}, R. and {Engel}, H.},
    title = "{Stellar and Molecular Gas Kinematics Of NGC 1097: Inflow Driven by a Nuclear Spiral}",
  journal = {\apj},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {0903.0313},
 keywords = {galaxies: active, galaxies: individual: NGC 1097, galaxies: kinematics and dynamics, galaxies: nuclei, galaxies: spiral, infrared: galaxies},
     year = 2009,
    month = sep,
   volume = 702,
    pages = {114-128},
      doi = {10.1088/0004-637X/702/1/114},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2009ApJ...702..114D},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{Riffel-Rogerio+09,
   author = {{Riffel}, R. and {Pastoriza}, M.~G. and {Rodr{\'{\i}}guez-Ardila}, A. and 
    {Bonatto}, C.},
    title = "{Probing the near-infrared stellar population of Seyfert galaxies}",
  journal = {\mnras},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {0907.4144},
 primaryClass = "astro-ph.CO",
 keywords = {stars: AGB and post-AGB , circumstellar matter , infrared: stars},
     year = 2009,
    month = nov,
   volume = 400,
    pages = {273-290},
      doi = {10.1111/j.1365-2966.2009.15448.x},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2009MNRAS.400..273R},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{Riffel-Rogerio+11a,
   author = {{Riffel}, R. and {Riffel}, R.~A. and {Ferrari}, F. and {Storchi-Bergmann}, T.
    },
    title = "{Intermediate-age stars as the origin of low stellar velocity dispersion nuclear rings: the case of Mrk 1157}",
  journal = {\mnras},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {1105.2487},
 keywords = {methods: data analysis, galaxies: individual: Mrk 1157, galaxies: individual: NGC 591, galaxies: Seyfert, galaxies: stellar content},
     year = 2011,
    month = sep,
   volume = 416,
    pages = {493-500},
      doi = {10.1111/j.1365-2966.2011.19061.x},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011MNRAS.416..493R},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{Riffel-Rogemar+10a,
   author = {{Riffel}, R. and {Storchi-Bergmann}, T. and {Riffel}, R. and 
    {Pastoriza}, M.~G.},
    title = "{Intermediate-age Stars as Origin of the Low-velocity Dispersion Nuclear Ring in Mrk 1066}",
  journal = {\apj},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {1002.2534},
 keywords = {galaxies: individual: Mrk 1066, galaxies: nuclei, galaxies: Seyfert, galaxies: stellar content, infrared: galaxies},
     year = 2010,
    month = apr,
   volume = 713,
    pages = {469-474},
      doi = {10.1088/0004-637X/713/1/469},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010ApJ...713..469R},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,maxnames=1,uniquelist=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This citation sequence should appear in the text as
(Cid Fernandes et al. 2005, Davies et al. 2007, 2009, Riffel et al., 2009, 2010, 2011) {\bf and so it does}
\parencite{Cid-Fernandes+05,Davies+07,Davies+09, Riffel-Rogerio+09,Riffel-Rogerio+11a,Riffel-Rogemar+10a}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

However, it seems that those are indeed two different authors (they are both referred to in `Riffel-Rogerio+11a`). If this is so, you should stick with the "A." and thank `biblatex` for not letting you make a wrong citation.

[image].

In this case, if you wish to have just the surname for both authors, although equal, you should add `uniquename=false` to the options of `biblatex`.

Comment: Thanks, Actually the R. A is my brother. Once there is only one citation starting with R. A. for this year, and it is listed separate on the references list, there is no mistake with the citation. The uniquename option solved my problem. Thanks.