# getting rid of initials in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber

Since some update biblatex inserts initials into the main text when there are two authors with the same last name. This also happens for "Carl J. Pollard" vs. "Carl Pollard". Is there a switch to suppress these initals?

Comment: Please consider showing an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that lets us reproduce what you get. At the moment I guess you want `uniquename=false`.

Comment: See [biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864), [Literature with Biber generates strange citations: firstnames appear erratically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864)

Comment: Any news here? Did `uniquename=false` help you?

Comment: Can we close your question as a duplicate?

Comment: Yes, please and sorry that I did not find the original question.

Comment: Don't worry about it, these kinds of duplicates are much easier to find if you know the answer already.