# First name appears in text-citations at specific circumstances

Tags: biblatex

Now, I stuck at a specific trouble and would like to ask you about this. I am using Biblatex and Biber for citations and generate citations in the text via `\cite{}` or `\citep{}`.

This works perfectly, with the exception of following entry in the bib-file:

```
@thesis{kohl_2000,  
    author = {Kohl, Martin},
    location = {Sample},
    title = {Sample},
    institution = {Sample},
    type = {phdthesis}, 
    date = {2000}
}
```

Here, I get **(cf. Kohl Martin 2000)** instead of **(cf. Kohl 2000)** by using the command `\citep[cf.][]{kohl_2000}`. If I change the last name, it works correctly again. It seams that it only appears, if the last name is “Kohl” (also at other publication types). Do you have any idea, why this strange error occurs?

Comment: At least you have to tell us which bib style you are using

Comment: Do you have a Steffen Kohl in your bibliography?

Comment: Please post a minimal working example to reproduce the issue. Questions needed this for decades, it is not a new thing. Welome.

Comment: Actually it would have to be a Maria Kohl, Steffen would give 'S. Kohl'. We need to see an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) and know your bib style to be sure, but I guess this is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick help :-)!! In the last hour, I tried to compose a MWE, but failed as it didn’t appear in a small environment. As moewe wrote, it was (tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864) / (tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864) and disappeared with adding `uniquename=false` and `uniquelist=false`. Thank you very much :-)!!!