# Citing two authors/Journals: Issue(Number)

Tags: biblatex

A while back, this customized Bib-style has been craftet for me on this platform and it has been working great ever since. Now, I have to change it up a little bit but don't know how: Whenever I'm citing a book/article that's been written by two people, the initial of the second author's first name shows up. This hasn't been a problem, but now I've been told that I should get rid of it... I know what the different parts of the code do, but I don't think just deleting a part of the code will do the trick (it hasn't yet for me at least) so I need your help! Thank you so much in advance!

Edit: I have added my entire (messy...) preamble because I seem to have lost the overview over everything... I'll have to sort this out soonish. Also I have added two 'problematic' Bib entries: knobel2007a produces "Knobel/C. ( Lankshear (2007)" instead of the desired "Knobel/Lankshear (2007)" (I know that the basic problem lies in the fact that I have manually added (eds.) after their names, but this makes other entries shorter). The other one in berg2012a that produces in the bibliography "In: Written Language and Literacy 15.1" when I want it to be "In: Written Language and Literacy 15(1)" (The journal title itself should remain cursive while the rest is upright).

If there is still information missing, please let me know and thank you for your time you've already spent helping me!

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={* Caps}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\setmonofont{Old Standard}
\newfontfamily\russianfont{Old Standard}
\newfontfamily\ipafont{Doulos SIL}
\newfontfamily\churchslavonicfont{Ponomar Unicode}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{churchslavonic}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
%\setotherlanguages{german,romanian,russian,churchslavonic}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}

\usepackage{yfonts}
%\usepackage{tipa}
%\usepackage{ifxetex}
%\usepackage{combelow}
\usepackage{hanging}
\setlength\columnsep{20pt}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[english]{fancyref}
\renewcommand{\fancyrefdefaultformat}{plain}
\renewcommand{\fancyrefdefaultspacing}{\fancyreftightspacing}
\newcommand*{\fancyrefapplabelprefix}{app}
\newcommand*{\appendname}{appendix}
\frefformat{plain}{\fancyrefapplabelprefix}{\appendname\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1}
\renewcommand*{\fancyrefseclabelprefix}{sec}
\newcommand*{\sectionname}{section}
\frefformat{plain}{\fancyrefseclabelprefix}{\sectionname\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1.}
\newcommand*{\fancyrefsublabelprefix}{sub}
\newcommand*{\subsectionname}{subsection}
\frefformat{plain}{\fancyrefsublabelprefix}{\subsectionname\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1.}
\renewcommand*{\fancyreftablabelprefix}{tab}
\renewcommand*{\tablename}{table}
\frefformat{plain}{\fancyreftablabelprefix}{\tablename\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1.}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\addtokomafont{labelinglabel}{\sffamily}

%%Tables%%
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage[footnote,printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}
\deffootnote[1.0em]{1.0em}{1.0em}
    {\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\,\enskip}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\mdseries\rmfamily}
\onehalfspacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

%%ToC%%
\KOMAoptions{
    toc=sectionentrydotfill,
    listof=totoc
}

\newkomafont{standardsection}{\Large}
\newkomafont{nsection}{\usekomafont{standardsection}\slshape}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
level=\sectiontocdepth,%
beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt,%
indent=0pt,%
numwidth=1.5em,%
entryformat=\usekomafont{sectionentry}\textsl%
]{section}{nsection}

\newcommand*\usensection{% define switch to nsection
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{1em plus 1pt}}% additional space in TOC before the first nsection entry
    \setkomafont{section}{\usekomafont{nsection}}%
    \renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{\addtocentrydefault{nsection}{##1}{##2}}%
}
\newcommand*\usestandardsection{% define switch to standard section
    \setkomafont{section}{\usekomafont{standardsection}}%
    \renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{\addtocentrydefault{section}{##1}{##2}}%
}

\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\clearpage}

%%Bibliography%%
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{TransAlph.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{references={Bibliography}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
        \clearname{editor}%
        \newunit}%
    \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
    \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+othersstrg}{\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{bytranslator+othersstrg}{\usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{bytypestrg}[2]{%
    \iffieldundef{#1type}
    {\bibstring{#2}}
    {\ifbibxstring{\thefield{#1type}}
        {\bibstring{\thefield{#1type}}}
        {\printtext{\thefield{#1type}}}}}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{/}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\providecommand*{\iflabeldateisdate}{%
    \ifboolexpr{%
        not test {\iffieldundef{labeldatesource}}
        and 
        (test {\iffieldequalstr{labeldatesource}{}} 
        or test {\iffieldequalstr{labeldatesource}{year}})}}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{origdate}%
        \setunit*{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
            \iflabeldateisdate
            {\iffieldnum{edition}
                {\printfield[superedition]{edition}%
                    \global\clearfield{edition}}
                {}%
                \printdateextra}
            {\printlabeldateextra}}}}

\newbibmacro*{origdate}{%
    \iffieldundef{origyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[brackets]{\printorigdate}}}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\newcounter{SprachB}
\newcommand{\SprachB}[1]{\refstepcounter{SprachB}\label{#1}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\singlespacing\footnotesize}

\newcommand{\graphem}[1]{\guilsinglleft {#1}\guilsinglright}
\newcommand{\ipa}[1]{{\ipafont {#1}}}
\newcommand{\aks}[1]{{\churchslavonicfont {#1}}}
\newcommand{\rus}[1]{{\russianfont {#1}}}
\newcommand{\phonem}[1]{/\ipa{#1}/}
\newcommand{\phon}[1]{[\ipa{#1}]}

\newcommand{\sog}[1]{‘{#1}’}
\newcommand{\zit}[1]{“{#1}”}

\hyphenation{Script-Ora-lia}

\usepackage{silence}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\cfoot{}
\ofoot{\pagemark\hspace{-.5cm}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{knobel2007a,
Title                    = {A New Literacies Sampler \textup{(New Literacies and Digital Epistemologies\,29)}},
Author                   = {Knobel, Michele and Lankshear, Colin (eds.)},
Keywords                 = {sek},
Location                 = {New\,York},
Publisher                = {Peter Lang},
Year                     = {2007}
}
@Article{berg2012a,
Title                    = {Identifying Graphematic Units. Vowel and Consonant Letters},
Author                   = {Berg, Kristian},
Journal                  = {Written Language \& Literacy},
Keywords                 = {sek},
Number                   = {1},
Pages                    = {26--45},
Volume                   = {15},
Year                     = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Example sentence \textcite[cf.][3--6]{knobel2007a}.\\
Another example sentence \parencite[][39]{berg2012a}.
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please consider turning that snippet of code into a fully functioning [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). In particular make sure that we can compile the complete code by copying and pasting it into an empty document *and* include an example of a problematic `.bib` entry.

Comment: For now note that the code as shown does not influence the citations significantly, i.e. it does not change anything for the citations compared to `style=authoryear` except for minor punctuation. At the moment I assume you have the problem described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864, but without a complete example it is kind of hard to tell.

Comment: Please also link and attribute the style you're using if you got it by asking for help here (or elsewhere online). Context helps.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I'll add everything else now! Sorry for still not getting it right sometimes...

Comment: Before I have a closer look note that `author = {Knobel, Michele and Lankshear, Colin (eds.)},` is a bad idea, editors should be given as `editor = {Knobel, Michele and Lankshear, Colin},` instead no matter how short this makes other entries.

Comment: If *New Literacies and Digital Epistemologies* is a journal, then `knobel2007a` should be an `@article`. But for me this rather looks like a `series` in which case `knobel2007a` should be a `@collection`.

Comment: @moewe thank you! this simple change from 'author' to 'editor' did the trick! this was shamefully easy and I seem to keep forgetting that LaTeX is 'smarter' than I think...
yes, it is a book that appears in a series but the series is not that important; I would be able to leave it out completely, so the single book from the series is definitely in the center of attention

Comment: Don't forget the `\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}` though.

Comment: I'll have a look at the other issue tomorrow, but please consider asking only one thing per question in the future. That makes it easier to answer your question and makes it more relevant for other people. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the unnecessary stuff and making the code compilable, the output for me is

[image: Example sentence Knobel/Lankshear (cf. 2007: 3–6). Another example sentence (Berg 2012: 39).\Berg, Kristian (2012): “Identifying Graphematic Units. Vowel and Consonant Letters”. In: Written Language & Literacy 15.1: 26–45. Knobel, Michele/Lankshear, Colin (eds.) (2007): A New Literacies Sampler (New Literacies and Digital Epistemologies 29). New York: Peter Lang.\]

so I can not reproduce the weird name issue.

But still

```
author = {Knobel, Michele and Lankshear, Colin (eds.)},
```

in `knobel2007a` is wrong. If the two are editors they should be marked as such properly with

```
editor = {Knobel, Michele and Lankshear, Colin},
```

Biber/BibTeX can get confused parsing the name with the appended `(eds.)` and produce weird output because of that. What you are seeing *could* be explained if you have a second source authored or edited by Colin Lankshear (or any other Lankshear for that matter). In that case the `uniquename` feature would try to distinguish `Lankshear, Colin` and `Lanksehar, Colin (eds.)` thinking that the two are different people, so it adds the name initial, because `Lanksehar, Colin (eds.)` is not quite the best input, Biber thinks the initials are "C. (. Lankshear" and prints that. Name disambihuation can be turned off as explained in [biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864) and [Literature with Biber generates strange citations: firstnames appear erratically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864).

It also seems to me as though `knobel2007a` is actually a `@collection` and not a `@book`. A `@book` is normally a work that was written in its entirety by the same set of authors, while a `@collection` is a, well ... collection of contributions by different authors curated by editors.

For the `volume`(`number`) thing you only need to redefine the bibmacro `volume+number+eid` and change the field format for `number`. See the MWE below.

I have slightly modernised your code for `biblatex` 3.11 and so with

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{references={Bibliography}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+othersstrg}{\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{bytranslator+othersstrg}{\usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{bytypestrg}[2]{%
  \iffieldundef{#1type}
    {\bibstring{#2}}
    {\ifbibxstring{\thefield{#1type}}
       {\bibstring{\thefield{#1type}}}
       {\printtext{\thefield{#1type}}}}}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{origdate}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printtext[parens]{%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\iffieldnum{edition}
            {\printfield[superedition]{edition}%
             \global\clearfield{edition}}
            {}%
          \printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}

\newbibmacro*{origdate}{%
  \iffieldundef{origyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[brackets]{\printorigdate}}}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  %\setunit*{\adddot}%<- comment this
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{knobel2007a,
  title     = {A New Literacies Sampler},
  editor    = {Knobel, Michele and Lankshear, Colin},
  keywords  = {sek},
  location  = {New York},
  publisher = {Peter Lang},
  year      = {2007},
  series    = {New Literacies and Digital Epistemologies},
  number    = {29},
}
@article{berg2012a,
  title    = {Identifying Graphematic Units. Vowel and Consonant Letters},
  author   = {Berg, Kristian},
  journal  = {Written Language \& Literacy},
  keywords = {sek},
  number   = {1},
  pages    = {26--45},
  volume   = {15},
  year     = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Example sentence \textcite[cf.][3--6]{knobel2007a}.
Another example sentence \parencite[][39]{berg2012a}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

we obtain

[image: Example sentence Knobel/Lankshear (cf. 2007: 3–6). Another example sentence (Berg 2012: 39).\Berg, Kristian (2012): “Identifying Graphematic Units. Vowel and Consonant Letters”. In: Written Language & Literacy 15(1): 26–45.\Knobel, Michele/Lankshear, Colin (eds.) (2007): A New Literacies Sampler. New Literacies and Digital Epistemologies 29. New York: Peter Lang.]

Comment: I have copied your solution and everything worked great until yesterday. Now, my file doesn't compile any more but gives me two warnings and two errors:
Error: Undefined control sequence. \DeclareDelimAlias
Error: Missing \begin{document}. \DeclareDelimAlias{f
Warning: Delimiter 'multinamedelim' in context 'bib' already defined, overwriting
Warning: Delimiter 'nametitledelim' in context 'bib' already defined, overwriting

Also, my JabRef doesn't offer @Collection (strangely just @Incollection) but even if I change the entries in question manually, the errors/warnings remain.

Comment: @LajosH `Error: Undefined control sequence. \DeclareDelimAlias` suggests that your `biblatex` version is outdated. It would surprise me if the code worked before on the same installation, though.

Comment: That's why I am so confused as well! It worked until it didn't anymore... I've checked and biber is version 2.6 but I cannot find the 3.11 version for fedora =( Is there a possibility to make the code compatible to 2.6?

Comment: @LajosH Biber 2.6 works together with `biblatex` 3.5 and 3.6. `biblatex` 3.6 was released two years ago, so maybe it is time for an update. Most changes I applied were just to modernise your code. You can take your old code from your question. If I'm not mistaken the only stuff I added was `\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}` and the `\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}` block, which should work even in older versions. Just copy that bit.

Comment: @LajosH Since I don't have `biblatex` 3.6 I can't test the code, but https://gist.github.com/moewew/2e80191d73f380c19bf4060c35db11f8 should more or less work. It should definitely not throw errors about `\DeclareDelimAlias`.