# edition in superscript before author in citations

Tags: biblatex, biber, superscripts

it's me again.
My advisor looked through my first drafts for my thesis and was overall very pleased but pointed out that she wants to see the edition of a work (@book or @collection) in superscript before the author in every citation like this:

> "Very smart quote." (Dürscheid ⁵2016: 13)

Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{TransAlph.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{references={Bibliography}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
        \clearname{editor}%
        \newunit}%
    \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
    \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+othersstrg}{\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}} 
\renewbibmacro*{bytranslator+othersstrg}{\usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{bytypestrg}[2]{%
    \iffieldundef{#1type}
    {\bibstring{#2}}
    {\ifbibxstring{\thefield{#1type}}
        {\bibstring{\thefield{#1type}}}
        {\printtext{\thefield{#1type}}}}}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{/}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\providecommand*{\iflabeldateisdate}{%
    \ifboolexpr{%
        not test {\iffieldundef{labeldatesource}}
        and 
        (test {\iffieldequalstr{labeldatesource}{}} 
        or test {\iffieldequalstr{labeldatesource}{year}})}}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{origdate}%
        \setunit*{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
            \iflabeldateisdate
            {\iffieldnum{edition}
                {\printfield[superedition]{edition}%
                    \global\clearfield{edition}}
                {}%
                \printdateextra}
            {\printlabeldateextra}}}}

\newbibmacro*{origdate}{%
    \iffieldundef{origyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[brackets]{\printorigdate}}}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}


\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}} 
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    %\setunit*{\adddot}%<- comment this
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{eid}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{durscheid2016a,
   Title                    = {Einführung in die Schriftlinguistik \textup{(UTB\,3740)}},
   Author                   = {Dürscheid, Christa},
   Keywords                 = {sek},
   Location                 = {Göttingen},
   Publisher                = {Andenhoeck \& Ruprecht},
   Year                     = {2016},
   Edition                  = {5},
   Origyear                 = {2002} }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Another example sentence \parencite[][16]{durscheid2016a}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you do for `@incollection` or `@inbook` entries? Do they still get the edition superscript even though, strictly speaking, it refers to their `booktitle` and not `title`.

Comment: Just in case you really use that entry in your document, please double check the `publisher` field. The publisher in Göttingen is called `Vandenhoeck \& Ruprecht` with a **V**.

Answer (score 3):

We just need to tell the citation macros to copy what the bibliography does

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldnum{edition}}
                   and test {\iflabeldateisdate}}
         {\printfield[superedition]{edition}}
         {}%
       \printlabeldateextra}}}
```

If you are still using an outdated pre-3.8 version of `biblatex` (I think you used to use 3.6, cf. the discussion below the answer in [Citing two authors/Journals: Issue(Number)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438933/35864)), replace `cite:labeldate+extradate` with `cite:labelyear+extrayear`, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/wiki/Name-Changes.

[image: "Another example sentence (Dürscheid <sup>5</sup>2016: 16)." The 5 appears in superscript position directly before the year.]