# Biber prints first letter of prename

Tags: biber

I use biber for citations as follows:

```
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    maxbibnames=99
    ]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% Based on name:andothers from biblatex.def
    \ifboolexpr{
        test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
        and
        test \ifmorenames
    }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
        {\finalandcomma}
        {}%
        \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}

\addbibresource{bib/refs.bib}
```

And I have in my refs.bib two differnet authors with the same name. Biber now alwas prints something like this: `(D. Name et al., 2017)` when using `\parencite(Name2017)`. If I `\parencite()` an author with a unique surname I only get `(Name et al. 2017)`. How do I change the setting of biber to get alwas only `(Name et al. 2017)`, no matter how often this name is in my bibliography?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- add the used bib entry(s) to your question and make your given code snippet compilable. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ... Perhaps you can use `maxbibnames=1`, but from the given infos that is not sure ...

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864. You may also be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864.

Comment: Any news here? Did `uniquename` and `uniquelist` help you? If not, please extend the code shown so far into a fully compilable example *document* with relevant `.bib` entries that reproduces the issue. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864. These issues are very likely context dependent, so it is crucial that you test your MWE and make sure that it reproduces the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

add `uniquename=false` to package options:

```
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    maxbibnames=99,
    uniquename=false,
    ]{biblatex}
```

Comment: I got rid of the first letter but now I get the names of the first two authors: ```(Name, Name, et al., 2017)```... can I change this too?

Comment: @lefrcom Unfortunately, we can't say with certainty what that is. My best guess is `uniquelist`, but it might be something else.

Comment: @moewe, thanks ```uniquelist=False``` together with ```uniquenames=False``` works perfectly for me! Thanks.