# Three authors becomes two names followed by et al. when cited in text

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have the following biblatex setup:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, citestyle=authoryear, natbib=true, maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
```

I have a citation with three authors, and when I use `\citet*{thompson_feature_2005}` I correctly get `Thompson, Hamilton and Rust (2005)` in the text.

But when I use `\citet{thompson_feature_2005}` (without the *) I incorrectly get `Thompson, Hamilton et al. (2005)`, it should be `Thompson et al. (2005)`.

The reason I use the words *correctly* and *incorrectly* is that this is the only citation that behaves this way. Other three author citations works like intended.

---

Heres the biblatex for this particular citation which doesn't work as intended:

```
@article{thompson_feature_2005,
    title = {Feature Fatigue: When Product Capabilities Become Too Much of a Good Thing},
    volume = {42},
    issn = {0022-2437, 1547-7193},
    url = {http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1509/jmkr.2005.42.4.431},
    doi = {10.1509/jmkr.2005.42.4.431},
    pages = {431--442},
    number = {4},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Marketing Research},
    shortjournal = {Journal of Marketing Research},
    author = {Thompson, Debora V. and Hamilton, Rebecca W. and Rust, Roland T.},
    urldate = {2020-02-11},
    date = {2005-11},
    langid = {english}
}
```

Here is citation with three authors that works as intended:

```
@article{schleyer_what_2007,
    title = {What is user-centered design?},
    volume = {138},
    issn = {0002-8177},
    url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0002817714631640},
    doi = {10.14219/jada.archive.2007.0319},
    language = {en},
    number = {8},
    urldate = {2020-02-28},
    journal = {The Journal of the American Dental Association},
    author = {Schleyer, Titus K. L. and Thyvalikakath, Thankam P. and Hong, Jason},
    month = aug,
    year = {2007},
    pages = {1081--1082}
}
}
```

The only difference I can find on the author names is that Schleyer in the second citation has two middle name initials, and Jason Hong doesn't have a middle name initial. But I don't think that is the problem.

---

If I remove the middle name initials from the authors in the biblatex file like this:

```
@article{thompson_feature_2005,
    title = {Feature Fatigue: When Product Capabilities Become Too Much of a Good Thing},
    volume = {42},
    issn = {0022-2437, 1547-7193},
    url = {http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1509/jmkr.2005.42.4.431},
    doi = {10.1509/jmkr.2005.42.4.431},
    pages = {431--442},
    number = {4},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Marketing Research},
    shortjournal = {Journal of Marketing Research},
    author = {Thompson, Debora and Hamilton, Rebecca and Rust, Roland},
    urldate = {2020-02-11},
    date = {2005-11},
    langid = {english}
}
```

I get the following by using `\citet{thompson_feature_2005}`: `D. Thompson et al. (2005)` in the text, which is also wrong.

---

Have anyone here experienced something similar?

---

#### EDIT:

I have created a minimal working example that is as close as I can get to the original document without sharing the whole document. It includes all the usepackage's. I also tried to mimick the use of subfiles, but I am not sure if that made any sense. **Unfortunately I am not able to recreate the problem with the given example, as it works as intended.**

I discovered that the citations appear as intended in another subfile-section that shares the same bibliography.

I will continue to troubleshoot, but I might have to write the citations manually.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc,url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\urlstyle{sf}
\usepackage[]{quoting}
\usepackage{babel, textcomp, csquotes, varioref, graphicx, layout, nameref, xfrac}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\captionsetup[subfigure]{margin=.8cm, font=footnotesize}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\graphicspath{{img/}{../src/img/}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=.5cm]{caption}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
\usepackage[page,titletoc,title]{appendix}
\addto\captionsnorsk{%
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Vedlegg}
  \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Vedlegg}
  \renewcommand\appendixtocname{Vedlegg}
}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

%%%%%%%%% Biblatex %%%%%%%%% 
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, citestyle=authoryear, natbib=true, maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{norsk}{norsk-apa}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
%\loadglsentries{src/glossary.tex}
\raggedbottom

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{thompson_feature_2005,
    title = {Feature Fatigue: When Product Capabilities Become Too Much of a Good Thing},
    volume = {42},
    issn = {0022-2437, 1547-7193},
    url = {http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1509/jmkr.2005.42.4.431},
    doi = {10.1509/jmkr.2005.42.4.431},
    pages = {431--442},
    number = {4},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Marketing Research},
    shortjournal = {Journal of Marketing Research},
    author = {Thompson, Debora V. and Hamilton, Rebecca W. and Rust, Roland T.},
    urldate = {2020-02-11},
    date = {2005-11},
    langid = {english}
}

@article{schleyer_what_2007,
    title = {What is user-centered design?},
    volume = {138},
    issn = {0002-8177},
    url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0002817714631640},
    doi = {10.14219/jada.archive.2007.0319},
    pages = {1081--1082},
    number = {8},
    journaltitle = {The Journal of the American Dental Association},
    shortjournal = {The Journal of the American Dental Association},
    author = {Schleyer, Titus K. L. and Thyvalikakath, Thankam P. and Hong, Jason},
    urldate = {2020-02-28},
    date = {2007-08-01},
    langid = {english}
}



\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{workingsample.tex}
    \documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
    \begin{document}
        \section{Correct and desired in-text citation with three authors}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \citet{schleyer_what_2007}
            \item \citet*{schleyer_what_2007} 
        \end{itemize}{}
        
        \section{Incorrect in-text citation with three authors}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \citet{thompson_feature_2005}
            \item \citet*{thompson_feature_2005} 
        \end{itemize}{}
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\subfile{workingsample.tex}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please prepare a complete [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe. If I take the code fragments you proveded so far and make a MWE myself, I get a different result than the one you describe.

Comment: I don't have time right now to look into this in more detail (not least because the question is missing a complete yet *minimal* example document that reproduces the issue), but you may want to have a look at the `uniquelist` and `uniquename` options. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864,
https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864 and
https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864.

Comment: Thanks for all the interest in solving this. I updated with a working example now, unfortunately I am not able to recreate the problem (so it might be to no use). I will continue to troubleshoot. The behaviour of how it appears is so inconsistent that it hardly makes sense.

Comment: One more thing: In general I would advise against mixing APA style with other styles as in `style=apa, citestyle=authoryear,`. `biblatex-apa` does a lot of work to implement APA guidelines and this makes it a bit harder to customise and tricky to combine with others styles. Stick to `style=apa,` if you want APA style or to `style=authoryear,` if you want a generic author-year style (which can be customised); but don't combine the two unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you moewe! I didn't see your reply before I commented. It seems like setting `uniquelist=false` did the trick (even though the only other incident of the same author has a different year, I guess they made it so for readability). And thank you for the recommendations on style, will keep to one of them.