# Author names included in citation

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber

I am writing a fairly large LaTeX document, and I started seeing an odd behaviour with citations, where the name of the author is included in the citation:

[image]

Unfortunately, I did not manage to reproduce this behaviour with an MWE. The following MWE works as expected, and contains essentially all elements that have something to do with the bibliography (as far as I know):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Input encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Font encoding

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
    %bibstyle=authoryear,
    %citestyle=authoryear,
    style=philosophy-modern,
    hyperref=true,
    %backref=true,
    backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{papers.bib}
\defbibheading{papers}{\section*{Journal Articles}}
\renewcommand{\cite}{\parencite}

\begin{document}

\cite{wu2022correction}

\printbibheading
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

% Journal articles
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Journal Articles}
\printbibliography[heading=papers,type=article]

\end{document}
```

with the following article in `papers.bib`:

```
@article{wu2022correction,
  title     = {Correction Schemes for Absolute Binding Free Energies Involving Lipid Bilayers},
  author    = {Wu, Zhiyi and Biggin, Philip C},
  journal   = {Journal of chemical theory and computation},
  volume    = {18},
  number    = {4},
  pages     = {2657--2672},
  year      = {2022},
  publisher = {ACS Publications}
}
```

[image]

Is this a known issue? It seems to only appear when the bibliography becomes large. I've been puzzled by this problem for a while, any pointers on how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without an example that reproduces the issue it is hard to say anything conclusively, but I'd say the most likely explanation is `biblatex`'s `uniquename` feature. If you have different authors with the same family name (or the same author in different versions, e.g. "Don Knuth" vs "Donald Knuth" vs "Donald E. Knuth"),  `biblatex` will try to distinguish those different authors by adding given name initials or even the full name. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I had several entries from the same author, and one had an additional initial. `uniquename=false` solves the issue. Thank you! I should also switch back from DuckDuckGo to Google, because I did not find the other questions you listed at all! =(