# Change citation style only for book

Tags: biblatex, citing

I use ovrleaf and I have to cite a book call it "book" with author "J.K. One". If I use `\Citet` with the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Keywords:}} #1}
\providecommand{\jel}[1]{\textbf{\textit{JEL Classification:}} #1}

\def\permille{\ensuremath{{}^\text{o}\mkern-5mu/\mkern-3mu_\text{oo}}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\footremember}[2]{%
    \footnote{#2}
    \newcounter{#1}
    \setcounter{#1}{\value{footnote}}%
}
\newcommand{\footrecall}[1]{%
    \footnotemark[\value{#1}]%
} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol} % used for the two-column index
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  useprefix,
  backend=biber,
  isbn = false,
  doi = false,
  language=auto,
  style=apa,
  sorting=nyt,
  natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliosim.bib}
\begin{document}
As noted by \Citet{one}
\end{document}
```

and `bibliosim.bib`:

```
@book{one,
  title  = {book},
  author = {J.K. One},
  year   = {2015},
  publisher={aa.}
}
```

I obtain:

> As noted by J.K. One (2015)

but I'd like to obtain:

> As noted by One (2015)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can't reproduce. I get "As noted by One (2015)"

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I am also unable to reproduce the issue you're reporting.

Comment: This example does not reproduce the issue, but my hunch is that it is due to the `uniquename` settings. In your actual document where the problem occurs you'll have another work by a different "One" (or by the same person, but with the name given in a different version like "J. K. One" and "Jane One"), `biblatex` will then try to disambiguate these names by adding initials. This can be turned off with `uniquename=false,`. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864

Comment: Any news here? As I said above the most likely cause of this is the `uniquename` feature. But with the MWE not reproducing the issue, we cannot be absolutely sure.