# Why all initials are shown for names with a prefix in a citation?

Tags: biblatex

The citations in footnotes behave differently in my text, depending whether the author names contains a prefix, such as `da` or `de`.

For example, `John Doe` is rendered as `Doe, Name of the book.` as I expect. But `Joao da Silva` renders as `J. d. Silva, Name of another work`. On the bibliography the full name is printed correctly. What could be causing this difference?

Here's how I'm including biblatex:

```
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=abnt,
  citestyle=authortitle,
  autocite=footnote,
  citecounter=true,
  citetracker=true,
  useprefix=false,
  ittitles,
  scbib,
  noslsn
]{biblatex}
```

Example entry from .bib that renders as `G. S. d. Sousa`:

```
@book{gabriel-soares-tratado,
    author={Gabriel Soares de Sousa},
    title={Tratado Descritivo do Brasil em 1587},
    publisher = { Typographia de João Ignacio da Silva},
    location = { Rio de Janeiro },
    year = 1879
}
```

Comment: Show us a `.bib` file entry that shows the problem.

Comment: But the `abnt` style is an `authoryear` style so you shouldn't be using it with an `authortitle` citation style.

Comment: Using `authoryear` does not fix the issue. Removing `style=abnt` (and corresponding flags) also does not fix the issue.

Comment: In a quick test I ran (https://gist.github.com/moewew/52c87f51e9a71f74b9a1d3db3a16559b) I get the output "Sousa, <title>" (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6beOL.png). If you get something else, something must be going on on your end. Please try to replicate the issue with a fully compilable example document and as little code as possible.

Comment: For now my working hypothesis would be that the output you get has to do with the `uniquename` feature. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864

Comment: Setting `uniquename=false` and `uniquelist=false` fixed the issue, thank you. If you change the answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I've deleted my answer, but you can see how without giving us a reproducible document to work with, it's not always easy to answer questions as you intend. And as I suggested, you should format your `.bib` entries using `Familyname, Given Names` rather than the way you have the name formatted in your example `.bib` item which can lead to unpredictable results.