# How to modify APA Biblatex style to look like "elsarticle-harv" style?

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, apa-style, author-number

I have been using the [`\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/elsarticle-harv.bst) style for a long time, since I newly swtiched to `biblatex` and it is only for `natbib`, so how to modify the default `biblatex` style or specifically the `APA` style, so that making the citation style same as `elsarticle-harv`.

The `elsarticle-harv` author-year citation style:

```
\cite{LathamVOF:2012} -----> Latham (2012)
\citep{LathamDEM:2012} -----> (Latham,2012) 

\cite{LathamM:2010} -----> Latham et al.(2010)   % multi-author
\cite{LathamMeer:2011} -----> Latham and Meer (2011)     % 2 authors

\cite{LathamVOF:2012,LathamDEM:2012} -----> Latham (2012a, b)
```

The new setting of `biblatex` is given:

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    refsection=chapter,
    natbib=true  ]  {biblatex} 
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
```

However, the `APA` sytle was like:

```
\cite{LathamVOF:2012} -----> Latham, 2012
\citep{LathamDEM:2012} -----> (Latham,2012)   % <--- same 

\cite{LathamM:2010} -----> Latham, A & B, 2010  % <--- too many cited authors!
\cite{LathamMeer:2011} -----> Latham & Meer, 2011     % & instead of and!

\cite{LathamVOF:2012,LathamDEM:2012} -----> Latham, 2012a,2012b
```

So how to make the year in `()` when using `\cite{}` and lessen the authors (if>3) as `FirstAuthor et al.`

**Edit1:**

using `￼\LetLtxMacro{\cite}{\citet}` makes year in `()`, however, the setting `maxcitenames=2` seems not working. Besides, how to change the `&` to `and`?

MWE codes:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book} 

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[ ]{libertine}
\usepackage[ T1 ]{fontenc}


\definecolor{DarkBlue}{RGB}{0,51,153}
    \hypersetup{
    colorlinks,%
    linktocpage =true,
    citecolor=DarkBlue,%
    filecolor=red,%
    linkcolor=DarkBlue,%
    urlcolor=green,
} % colorlinks setting


\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    refsection=chapter,
    maxcitenames=2,        
    natbib=true  ]  {biblatex} 
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\LetLtxMacro{\cite}{\citet}  % year in ()

\addbibresource{reffile.bib}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\citep[e.g.][]{Tsuji:2008, TsujiDEM:2008}   

\cite{TsujiDEM2D:2008, TsujiDEM:2008} 

\cite{Shirgaonkar:2009}. 

\citep{Sorensen:2006}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]
\end{document}
```

and `reffile.bib`

```
@ARTICLE{Tsuji:2008,
  author  = {Tsuji, T. and Yabumoto, K. and Tanaka, T. and Peter, B.},
  title   = {Spontaneous structures in three-dimensional bubbling gas-fluidized bed by paralled {DEM-CFD} coupling simulation},
  journal = {  Powder Technology },
  year    = { 2008  },
  volume  = { 184  },
  pages   = {  132-140 },
  number  = {5 }
  }

@ARTICLE{TsujiDEM:2008,
  author  = {Tsuji, T. },
  title   = {Spontaneous structures in three-dimensional bubbling},
  journal = {  Powder Technology },
  year    = { 2008  },
  volume  = { 11  },
  pages   = {  11-17 },
 number  = {2 }
  }

@ARTICLE{TsujiDEM2D:2008,
  author  = {Tsuji, T. },
  title   = {Spontaneous structures in 2-{D} bubbling },
  journal = {  Powder Technology },
  year    = { 2008  },
  volume  = { 10  },
  pages   = {  13-19 },
 number  = { 7}
  }


@ARTICLE{Shirgaonkar:2009,
  author  = {Shirgaonkar, A. A. and Maclver, M. A. and Patankar, N. A.},
  title   = {A new mathematical formulation and fast algorithm for fully resovled simulation of self-propulsion},
  journal = {Journal of Computional Physics},
  year    = { 2009  },
  volume  = { 228  },
  pages   = {  2366-2390 },
 number  = {11 }
  }

  @ARTICLE{Haeri:2012,
  author  = {Haeri, S. and Shrimpton, J. S.},
  title   = {On the application of immersed boundary, fictitious domain and body-conformal mesh methods to many particle multiphase flows},
  journal = {International Journal of Multiphase Flow},
  year    = { 2012  },
  volume  = { 40  },
  pages   = {  38-55 },
  number  = { 18}
  }

@BOOK{Sorensen:2006,
   author = {Sorensen, R. M.},
   title = { {Basic Coastal Engineering} },
   publisher = {Springer Science, New York},
   edition = {Third},
   year    = { 2006 },
   }
```

Output: Displaying 3-5 authors in citation looks really odd `:(`, but `maxcitenames` is not available in `APA`

[image]

The printed references style: Journal name and volume is `italic`, how to make it as normal font; or just make the `volume` number non-italic, because the combination *18*(5) (where 5 is the number) looks weird.

For comparison, the original `natbib` output is also attached:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue with the `maxcitenames` is that APA style requires that all the names be listed the first time the work is cited. This is controlled by the `labelname` format in `apa.cbx`. I modified

```
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
...
{\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{>}{5}}
             or test {\ifciteseen}}
...
}
```

to be

```
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
...
{\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{>}{\value{maxnames}}}}
...
}
```

I believe you can just copy the original and paste a modified version into your preamble or you can define your own citation style.

As for dealing with & and "and", I do

```
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace{}\bibstring{and}\space}
```

I cannot remember if this handles changes in language properly.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work :(, when I put it in preamble.

Comment: I forgot to add `makeletter....`, it did work

Answer (score 4):

The biblatex-apa package is carefully tailored to meet the standards of the APA style. Your requirements are relatively simple and likely have more in common with features of the standard `authoryear-comp` style.

Most of the changes you would need to make to `authoryear-comp` have already been addressed by other posts on this site.

- [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/4483)
- [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/4483)
- [Suppress "In:" biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/4483)

The following example should get you most of the way there. I used BibTeX as the backend here as I can't see why your style needs biber. If you wish to use biber, load biblatex with:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp,natbib,uniquename=false,
            uniquelist=false,maxcitenames=2,firstinits,dashed=false]{biblatex}
```

This will disable name and name list disambiguation. The latter overrides `maxcitenames=2` to ensure that name lists in citations are unique. Note that in switching between backends you should delete auxiliary files (*.aux, *.bbl, *.bcf, etc.) before re-compiling.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear-comp,natbib,maxcitenames=2,
  firstinits,dashed=false]{biblatex}

% \cite like \textcite
\renewrobustcmd*{\cite}{\citet}
\renewrobustcmd*{\Cite}{\Citet}
\renewrobustcmd*{\cites}{\textcites}

% all titles upright, no quotes
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1}

% no "In: " preceding journal titles
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

% volume (number)
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}}
    {\setunit*{\adddot}}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% no page prefix
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

% no parentheses around dates
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{year}{}{\printtext{\printdateextra}}}%

% no and before last name in list
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}}

% all names last-first
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite[e.g.][10--15]{glashow}, \citet[e.g.][10--15]{glashow} \\
\cite{companion}, \citet{companion}, \citep{companion} \\
\cite*{companion}, \citet*{companion} \\
\cites[e.g.][10--15]{bertram}[10--14]{knuth:ct:a} \\
\cite{glashow,bertram,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c} \\
\citet{glashow,bertram,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, now everything with use of this style is under control.

Answer (score 3):

To add the parenthesis to the citation produced with `\cite`, you can use the package `letltxmacro` to define `\cite` as `\citet`

```
￼\LetLtxMacro{\cite}{\citet}
```

The number of authors to be printed before using et. al. is controlled by the parameter `maxcitenames` as one of  the options of `biblatex`, i.e.

```
\usepackage[maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
```

Comment: The first command worked, but the option maxcitenames=2 did not change the maximum citation names.