# Bibliography style - help with bibtex

Tags: bibliographies

I need hel with the bibliography. This is how it appears in my document:

"Author name. Title. **: Journaltitle. (Date)."

But I'd like to remove "In:" before the journaltitle. How can I do that? Thank you in advance for your answers!

This is the packages I'm using for the bibliography:

```
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you provide us with a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). We need to know what package you are using to produce the bibliography and what style you are using.

Comment: Which bibliography style you are using? Please edit your post and put in the minimal code. And welcome to tex.SE.

Comment: In that case, might I direct you to this question: [Suppress “In:” biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864).