# Changing order of fields for @incollection / @inbook

Tags: biblatex, biber

For one chapter references (`@inbook{Ramberg2013`) I need to change the field order. The field order after `In:` needs to be `Initials. Surname of author/editor(s) followed by ed/eds. if relevant. _title in italics_ . Place: publisher, pages.`

The MWE:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}

\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{memoir} 

\usepackage{xpatch,etex,setspace,excludeonly,ifthen,etoolbox,logreq,makeidx,cals,graphicx}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,firstinits=true,uniquename=init,natbib=true,backend=biber,indexing=true,defernumbers=true,isbn=false,doi=false,dashed=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{ThesisMWE.bib} 

 % Bath Harvard formatting
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
% 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1\adddot\nopunct\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book,collection]{title}{{\mkbibemph{#1}\adddot\nopunct\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{urlseen}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

% Change to address: publisher
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{:\space}}% ADDED
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

% Initials always following surname in author field
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{liststop}}{1}
      {#1\addcomma\addspace #4\addcomma\isdot}
      {#1\addcomma\addspace #4}
    }
    {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
      {\addcomma\addspace #1\addcomma\addspace #4}
      {\addcomma\addspace\bibstring{and} #1\addcomma\addspace #4\addcomma\isdot}
    }%
  } 

% Custom strings
\DefineBibliographyStrings{british}{%
edition = {edn\adddot\nopunct\isdot},
in = {In\addcolon},
urlseen = {Accessed\addspace}
}

% Remove parentheses from year
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
      \begingroup%
        \clearfield{month}%
        \clearfield{day}%
    \ifboolexpr{%
      test {\iffieldundef{date}}
      and
      test {\iffieldundef{year}}
    }%
      {\iftoggle{bbx:nodate}{\printtext{%
        \midsentence\bibstring{nodate}}}{}}%
      {\printtext{\printdateextra}}%
       \endgroup}%
%   
% Dot after year
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\adddot\space}

% Custom volume(number) and pp. xx-yy
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The `.bib` file:

```
@collection{9Barnes1995,
    Address = {Cambridge},
    title = {The Cambridge Companion to Aristotle},
    Editor = {Jonathan Barnes},
    Publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    Year = {1995}
}

@inbook{Ramberg2013,
title={For the Sake of His Own Generation: Rorty on Destruction and Edification},
author={Bjorn Torgrim Ramberg},
year={2013},
address={London},
publisher={Bloomsbury Academic},
booktitle={Richard Rorty: From Pragmatist Philosophy to Cultural Politics},
editor={Alexander Gr{\"o}schner and Colin Koopman and Mike Sandbothe} 
}


@online{SEP-MP,
    Author = {Dancy, Jonathan},
    Editor = {Edward N. Zalta},
    Subtitle = {The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy},
    Title = {{M}oral {P}articularism},
    Edition="Spring 2009",
    Url = {http://plato.stanford.edu/archives/spr2009/entries/moral-particularism/},
    Urldate = {2010-08-06},
    Year = {2009}
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{Garside2008,
  author = {Darren Garside},
  title = {{U}sing {S}ocial {N}etwork {A}nalysis to analyse speaking \& listening
    in {P}hilosophy for {C}hildren communities of enquiry},
  booktitle = {British Educational Research Association Annual Conference},
  year = {2008},
  address = "Edinburgh: Edinburgh Napier University",
  date="2-5 September 2008"
}

@inbook{1Phillips2010,
    year={2010},
    Crossref = {9BaileyHandbook2010},
    booktitle={The Sage Handbook of Philosophy of Education},
    title={What is Philosophy of Education?},
    author={D. C. Phillips},

    pages={3--20}   
}

@inbook{1Barrow2010,
    year={2010},
    Crossref = {9BaileyHandbook2010},
    booktitle={The Sage Handbook of Philosophy of Education},
    title={Schools of Thought in Philosophy of Education?},
    author={Robin Barrow},

    pages={21--36}  
}

@book{9BaileyHandbook2010,
  title={The Sage Handbook of Philosophy of Education},
  editor={Richard Bailey and Robin Barrow and David Carr and Christine McCarthy},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Sage Publications Ltd},
  address={London}
}

@book{9BaileyHandbook2012,
  title={Mock entry to demonstrate difference between edited and authored entries},
  author={Richard Bailey and Robin Barrow and David Carr and Christine McCarthy},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Sage Publications Ltd},
  address={London}
}
```

Comment: Well, your issues seem to be related with the bibliography style you are using. I don't know which one you are using. But perhaps you need to create your own for get the references as you need or, find an style that works exactly as you need.

Comment: Some of your customisation is definitely being overridden by philosophy-classic since it works if I use authoryear instead. This isn't true of everything but it does get e.g. ", eds." rather than "(eds.)", for example. I don't think urlseen is a field. At least, it works if I kludge things and put \DeclareFieldFormat[online]{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{Accessed\addspace#1}} instead.

Comment: if it is this kind of last-minute situation i think you could just make hard changes to the .bib and .aux files. .

Comment: @cfr I might try reverting to authoryear.

Comment: @Aradnix jlovegren I simply don't have time to work out what you mean and implement those changes.

Comment: @cfr reverting to author year does help.  This makes sense since I used philosophy-classic when I thought I was working to a particular journal style.  Of course my University is using a more generic style so authoryear is more appropriate.

Comment: @DGarside Are there any issues remaining after reverting to `authoryear`? Anyway, I would not redefine `\DeclareNameFormat{author}` in the way you did, if it's only reversal of initials you're after, try `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}`, of course there is no need for that with `authoryear`.

Comment: @moewe One glaring issue - I need to remove `In:` from journal articles. I haven't throughly checked yet.

Comment: @DGarside If that's the only problem, you're almost done: see here [Suppress “In:” biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864).

Comment: @moewe Suppress link wwas good.  Multiauthor books no longer print out all authors.

Comment: @DGarside To get absolutely all authors in the bibliography try `maxbibnames=999` (it's a loading time option; there is also `maxcitenames` if you want to change the maximum number of authors displayed in citations) and `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}` (if you want the Oxford comma [your initial MWE had it] and use `british`, you'll also need `\AtBeginDocument{\def\finalandcomma{\addcomma}}`).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11986/discussion-between-dgarside-and-moewe)

Comment: I've now pruned the question down so that it is not too broad. Hopefully this will now be reconsidered.

Answer (score 2):

To fix #4: `@online entries` add:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{Available from\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
```

Comment: This answer refers to a previous (over-complex) version of the question.