# Proper use of in:, \intitlepunct for @inbook entries in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

The following code produces what are (to me) unexpected results and I would like to know where I am going wrong. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@bookinbook{robber-early-years,
  crossref  =   {robber-robberies},
  title     =   {Robbing Trains: The Early Years},
  pages     =   {33-245}}
@inbook{robber-greatest,
  crossref  =   {robber-robberies},
  title     =   {My Greatest Robbery Yet},
  pages     =   {456--468}}
@book{robber-robberies,
  author    =   {Robber, Great Train},
  title     =   {A Robber's Life},
  year      =   2014,
  publisher =   {Fictitious Emporium Ltd.},
  address   =   {Somewhere}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}
  % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10686/39222
  \renewbibmacro{in:}{%
    \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
\makeatother
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\autocites{robber-early-years}{robber-greatest}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

What I expect this to do for entry types which use the `bibmacro` `in:` and which are not of type `@article` is to use `in` or `In` followed by a breakable space *rather than* `in` or `In` followed by a colon etc. However, I get a full stop as well and I do not understand why:

[image: Unexpected full stops in bibliography]

I can avoid this by redefining the `@inbook` entry type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@bookinbook{robber-early-years,
  crossref  =   {robber-robberies},
  title     =   {Robbing Trains: The Early Years},
  pages     =   {33-245}}
@inbook{robber-greatest,
  crossref  =   {robber-robberies},
  title     =   {My Greatest Robbery Yet},
  pages     =   {456--468}}
@book{robber-robberies,
  author    =   {Robber, Great Train},
  title     =   {A Robber's Life},
  year      =   2014,
  publisher =   {Fictitious Emporium Ltd.},
  address   =   {Somewhere}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}
  % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10686/39222
  \renewbibmacro{in:}{%
    \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
\makeatother
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\makeatletter
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
%   \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
%   \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\autocites{robber-early-years}{robber-greatest}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Hacked bibliography less unwanted full stops]

But this is surely not the best way to do this. It strikes me as odd that the driver for `@inbook` tries to use the book author as well as the author. As I understand it, `@inbook` and `@bookinbook` are for precisely those cases in which the author of the whole is also the author of a distinct part. An example for `@bookinbook` mentioned in the manual is the collected works of an author. But in that case, you would not expect a distinct author and it seems silly to include the author twice when laying out the entry.

This makes me think that I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something here - either about how the commands work or about the intended purpose of these entry types.

If I stick to the standard definition of `in:`, I don't get spurious full stops but I do, of course, get the colon I wanted to get rid of. (This looks especially silly for non-article entries, in my view, and `in` is altogether unnecessary for article entries so eliminating the colon seemed a good option. The comment in the code is to the question I took the code from but I cannot get it to work 'right'.)

Can anybody explain how to do this correctly and how these are intended to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I can't promise I've understood it, I think that by using `\addspace` you are confusing the punctuation tracker. Because the tracker sees that no relevant punctuation mark has been printed, when the next `\newunit` occurs (immediately after `bybookauthor` has printed nothing), it backs up, removes your space, and inserts `\newunitpunct`.

You can sort this out by defining `\intitlepunct` as `\addspace\nopunct`, which I *think* should be safe in this context.

Comment: This seems to work great - thanks! I had wondered if it had to do with this but did not know how to trace it or correct for/work around it. This seems (on brief testing) to do the job nicely. I would like to understand better the underlying issue with the tracker. Do you know if this is documented somewhere?

Comment: It's quite extensively documented in the manual (around 4.7) but it is highly condensed.

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful. I find navigating the `biblatex` manual a bit challenging at times ;).

Answer (score 4):

`biblatex` has a punctuation tracker and a punctuation buffer, a `\newunit` or `\setunit` command inserts the respective punctuation mark into the buffer, it does not print the punctuation mark straight away, subsequent `\setunits` overwrite the buffer.

So the `\addspace` in the buffer is overwritten by the `\newunit` following the `bybookauthor` macro.
Luckily for us, the `biblatex` developers got into trouble with this concept at some point and decided to add `\printunit`. `\printunit` inserts a punctuation mark that persist in the buffer, i.e. cannot be overwritten by other `\setunits`.

If we add the `\printunit` command to the redefinition of `in:`

```
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\printunit{\intitlepunct}}}}
```

the output should be as expected. (I don't know why this is not the default, after all, the "in:" is always printed and one would want it to be followed by the proper punctuation mark as defined in `\intitlepunct`.)

This problem seems to occur only with `\intitlepunct` set to `\addspace` or `\space`, any of the other `\add` commands work like a charm without `\printunit`.

You can read more about the wonderful world of punctuation with `biblatex` in §4.7 *Punctuation and Spacing*, p. 189 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@bookinbook{robber-early-years,
  crossref  =   {robber-robberies},
  title     =   {Robbing Trains: The Early Years},
  pages     =   {33-245}}
@inbook{robber-greatest,
  crossref  =   {robber-robberies},
  title     =   {My Greatest Robbery Yet},
  pages     =   {456--468}}
@book{robber-robberies,
  author    =   {Robber, Great Train},
  title     =   {A Robber's Life},
  year      =   2014,
  publisher =   {Fictitious Emporium Ltd.},
  address   =   {Somewhere}}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\printunit{\intitlepunct}}}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \autocites{robber-early-years}{robber-greatest}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation and answer. Is this solution preferable to the use of `\nopunct` suggested by Paul Stanley in his answer? His seems to work well in the case I was dealing with but I'd prefer to use the most robust solution or I'm bound to get caught out at some point when I fail to notice unexpected results. (As happened initially in this case, in fact.)

Comment: For my own part I think the solutions are equally good/bad. In fact, I originally used moewe's but preferred `\nopunct` because I think it more accurately expresses the intention: his effectively means "punctuate this with `intitlepunct` (even if it's not punctuation)", whereas mine means "use a space, and no following punctuation". In this case, however, it comes to the same thing, I think.

Comment: At first, I thought my solution to be the more `biblatex`-y (that's why I posted it in the first place after Paul Stanley had already given an answer). But seeing that some of the things I expected when playing around with the punctuation did not come true - and given Paul Stanley's reasoning above - I tend to think that his solution as actually preferable in this case: it's slightly shorted and probably more meaningful.

Comment: @PaulStanley On wone thing though I have to disagree. I think my solution actually tells `biblatex`: "Print *this* 'punctuation' mark  (OK, in our case it is only a space: but now we use `\printunit` and that can be used for whitespace as well) after the 'in', *no matter what anyone else tells you*; make sure *it* is the thing that comes after the 'in'."

Comment: @moewe That's right ... nearly -- because technically I think `\printunit` doesn't actually print the unit: it sits it in the buffer but makes it persist there regardless of subsequent `\newunit` or `\setunit`s. But the actual printing only happens when the buffer clears. A second `\printunit` will still clobber it. But that's irrelevant in this case, and not a reason to prefer my solution!

Comment: @PaulStanley You are right. I should have probably said "print *this* punctuation mark *when you add punctuation the next time*".