# changing the value of biblatex `in:` macro based on value of field in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

## The problem

I'd like to display conference presentations with a different preposition introducing them.  E.g., in English, it would be preferable to have "At: Conference Name" than "In: Conference Name".  The latter appears because I've been recording conferences as articles, and the name of the conference as a journal—perhaps there is a better way?

## MWE

Here's an MWE for the normal behaviour:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{public2000,
  author = {Sam Public},
  year = {2000},
  journal = {Journal of Amazing Ideas},
  title = {Some Hargle Bargle},
  pubtype = {peerreviewied}
}

@article{public2001,
  author = {Sam Public},
  year = {2001},
  journal = {Conference of Amazing Ideas},
  title = {Some Hargle Bargle},
  pubtype = {presentation}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{public2000}, \cite{public2001}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And here's what it results in:
[image]

## Attempts at a solution

To obtain the desired behaviour, I've added a `pubtype` field (see MWE), and I've tried hardcoding the output to "At:" based on the value of `pubtype`:

```
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{
    \iffieldequalstr{pubtype}{presentation}{%
        \printtext{At:\intitlepunct}%
    }{%
      \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}%
    }%
  }{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to consider `pubtype` a valid field—or at least, it doesn't seem to be able to test its value.  (The output is unchanged, though it does print "At:" if take it out of the if block.)

I've tried defining `pubtype` as a field a few different ways based on answers that appeared to be related, but nothing seemed to change anything.

Comment: Is your `public2001` really an `@article` or rather an `@inprocedings`? Note that there already is the field `entrysubtype` which you could use instead of a self-defined `pubtype`.

Comment: Let's say that in this hypothetical example there could be both `@article`s and `@inproceedings`es :)  Are you implying that `entrysubtype` is limited to just `@inproceedings`, or does it work for anything?

Comment: No `entrysubtype` can be used for all entry types. I was just thrown off by the `@article`, with the intended code what is normally the `journal`/`journaltitle` would end up after the "At:" and I could not imagine that making sense (a conference is not a journal and vice versa), so I suggested `@inproceedings` where it could make sense.

Comment: If you mean that it might make sense to use `@inproceedings` for a conference presentation, then the conference would end up as the `booktitle`, which probably makes as much sense as `journal` or `journaltitle`.  And proceedings papers and presentations are different beasts anyway—you might want to cite one or the other, even when they have the same title, author, and year.  (Of course the proceedings paper would be preferable as a tangible source of information.)

Comment: Mhhh, my point is that this looks like an abuse of the `@article` type. Using `@inproceedings` is probably also a bit of a stretch over the intended meaning (published paper version), but it comes closer in meaning and has the additional advantage of `venue` and `eventdate` fields. In fact `@unpublished` might be an ever better possibility (that is what the talk is, after all), especially since it supports `eventtitle`, `eventdate` and `venue` since `biblatex` 3.11.

Comment: `@unpublished` indeed looks like a good fit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David Purton has answered the immediate issue at hand, but let me collect my comments and additional thoughts into an answer.

1. You could use bibstrings instead of a hard-coded "At:", that way it can be translated into other languages more easily.
2. All entry types support the `entrysubtype` field and some types support an additional `type` field (`@unpublished`, `@report`, `@thesis`, `@misc`, `@manual`, `@booklet`, ...). The contents of the `type` field are normally printed in the bibliography, `entrysubtype` is not printed. So you could just use `entrysubtype` instead of a self-defined `pubtype` that needs to be made kn known to `biblatex` and Biber with a `.dbx` file.
3. I would not use `@article` for talks/presentations. `@article`s are really only for papers published in a journal.

   - I would be kind of OK with using `@inproceedings`, but that is still a bit of a stretch. `@inproceedings` is intended for published papers in conference proceedings, so it comes closer to what we have here, but doesn't quite cut it. It has the advantage of supporting the useful fields `eventtitle`, `eventdate` and `venue`, though.
   - Since `biblatex` 3.11, `@unpublished` also supports `eventtitle`, `eventdate` and `venue` ([by popular demand](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/687)). So `@unpublished` is a very good idea if you are not too worried about backwards compatibility.

So I would probably try something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{public2000,
  author = {Sam Public},
  year = {2000},
  journal = {Journal of Amazing Ideas},
  title = {Some Hargle Bargle},
}

@unpublished{public2001,
  author       = {Sam Public},
  date         = {2001-04-06},
  eventtitle   = {Conference of Amazing Ideas},
  venue        = {Duckburg},
  eventdate    = {2001-04-05/2001-04-07},
  title        = {Some Hargle Bargle},
  type         = {presentation},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{at}
\NewBibliographyString{presentation}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
   at           = {at},
   presentation = {presentation}, 
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[unpublished]{eventtitle}{%
  \iffieldequalstr{type}{presentation}
    {\bibstring{at}\addcolon\space}
    {}%
  #1}

\begin{document}
\cite{public2000,public2001}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer not to see the "Presentation" in the bibliography, use `entrysubtype` instead of `type` (also in the test of the `eventtitle` field format).

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[unpublished]{eventtitle}{%
  \iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{presentation}
    {\bibstring{at}\addcolon\space}
    {}%
  #1}
```

Answer (score 3):

A custom field needs to be defined before you can use it.

You can put the definition in `biblatex-dm.cfg` in the same directory as your `tex` file.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{public2000,
  author = {Sam Public},
  year = {2000},
  journal = {Journal of Amazing Ideas},
  title = {Some Hargle Bargle},
  pubtype = {peerreviewied}
}

@article{public2001,
  author = {Sam Public},
  year = {2001},
  journal = {Conference of Amazing Ideas},
  title = {Some Hargle Bargle},
  pubtype = {presentation}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{pubtype}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\iffieldequalstr{pubtype}{presentation}
       {\printtext{At}}
       {\bibstring{in}}}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}}}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}

\begin{document}
\cite{public2000}, \cite{public2001}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would a custom field be defined in the `dbx` file?

Comment: You can do it in a few ways, e.g., with a source map or by one of the ways from section 4.5.4 of the `biblatex` manual. I'll update my answer for you.

Comment: So according to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175780/90570, I should be using `\printunit` too.  It makes the space (`\intitlepunct`) a much more reasonable size.

Comment: @JonathanW. Yes, good pick up. I'll update things.

Comment: If you are using `\printunit` you can move it out of the `\printtext` (that feels nicer to me) and you can even drop the `\printtext` for the `\bibstring`s.

Comment: @moewe, yes that is much neater.