# How to change separators in BibTex?

Tags: bibtex

According to the rules of my university, if an article from some journal was used, it should be separated with //.

Example: Lyness J. N. and Jespersen D. Moderate degree symmetric quadrature rules for the triangle//J. Inst. Math. Appl.

How should I do this? Do I have to change something in *.bst file?

Comment: You mean, there should be a line break between the article's name and the journal name? Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: Not a line break. These two symbols must be. I use plain.bst

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. And the only place where this unusual block divider is to be used is between the `title` and `journal` fields -- and nowhere else?

Comment: Yes, it's the only place.

Comment: `\begin{rant}` Wouldn't it be easier adopting a standard? `\end{rant}` You have all my sympathy. `;-)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you need to hack `plain.bst`. Replacing the `article` function in `plain.bst` with the following seems to do the trick:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  %new.block
  "//" *
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize *
      format.vol.num.pages output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Personally, I find the bst syntax to be quite painful, but you can read all about it in Patashnik's [Designing BibteX files](ftp://ftp.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/btxhak.pdf).

All that I have done above is to comment out the `new.block` line, added `"\\" *` to put your slashes after the title and then hacked the output of the journal's name so that no punctuation is added. I am sure that there are better ways to do this...

Comment: Thank you. I used *.bst change for something else found in this forum, so it's good both changes occur in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

## The dirty hack

This doesn't involve changing any `.bst` files, but will most certainly mess with the rest of your bibliography. If we look at the `.bbl` file created by `bibtex` we find

```
\newblock {\em The Journal of Narrative Technique}, ...
```

Hence we could redefine `\em` to expand to `// em`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{doody}
{\em Emphasized text}
\let\oldem=\em % save \em
\def\em{//\space\oldem}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}
\let\em=\oldem % restore \em
{\em Emphasized text}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

## Using `biblatex`

With `biblatex` everything is easier. We use

```
\renewbibmacro{in:}{...}
```

to [suppress "In:"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10686/10995) before the journal title and

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{// \emph{#1}}
```

to get the two slashes.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{\ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{// \emph{#1}}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{doody}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

(`biblatex` displays more fields than `bibtex` by default.)

> [image]