# What exactly is the relationship Biblatex refers to as an alias of an entry type? And how should the formatting of aliased entry types be configured?

Tags: biblatex

According to Biblatex's manual, the standard styles treat `@review` as an alias for `@article`:

> Reviews of some other work. This is a more specific variant of the `@article` type. The standard styles will treat this entry type as an alias for `@article`.

This led me to expect the same formatting to be applied to both kinds of entry. However, this does not appear to be the case:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{article,
  author    =   {Mouse, A.},
  title     =   {A Tall Tail},
  journal   =   {Tales to Nibble By},
  pages     =   {1--9},
  volume    =   31,
  number    =   4,
  year      =   1989,
}
@review{review,
  author    =   {Vole, Adrian},
  title     =   {Review of \emph{Great Grasses}, by A. N. Other-Mouse},
  journal   =   {Tales to Nibble By},
  pages     =   {23--4},
  volume    =   32,
  number    =   2,
  year      =   1990
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Rodent References]

Note two differences:

- The `@review` title is italicised; the `@article` title is quoted.
- `vol.` is included in the `@review` case but not the `@article` case.

Yet the only standard `.bbx` file to include the string `review` at all is `standard.bbx` which includes this line:

```
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{review}{article}
```

Moreover, nothing obvious to me in the `.sty` or `.def` files etc. explains the differences. There are some mentions of `review` here, but mostly as strings e.g. `reviewof` etc. which I take it are not responsible for formatting *entries* of type `@review`.

What exactly is the relationship Biblatex refers to as an `alias` of an entry type? And how should the formatting of aliased entry types be configured?

Comment: That is a very interesting question indeed. I cannot give an authoritative answer, but form what I have researched so far `\DeclareBibliographyAlias` really only triggers use of the same driver (as defined in `standard.bbx` for the standard styles). The differences you are seeing are mainly those caused by `\DeclareFieldFormat` where a difference still exists. Maybe I can find the code to explain the latter (the former is straightforward).

Comment: @moewe That's helpful, though I'd like to know more. I'm a bit confused, at this point, about the *purpose* of such aliases, since it seems difficult to understand why they don't get formatted in just the same way (from a design point of view). I guess the default `volume` format gets applied, which is intended for `@book` because `\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{#1}` does not affect `@review`? (Haven't found the other bit yet.)

Comment: Where the code is is a bit of a mystery. It would be really useful to produce a map of where things are defined in `biblatex`. But on the second part of your question, the alias sets the main type but there will also be a `type` field which is then used to control aspects of the formatting.

Comment: I think the purpose of `\DeclareBibliographyAlias` is something along the lines of "I would like to support this as a distinct entry type, but for my standard style purposes, the structure of expected output is sufficiently similar to <insert type here>". (Maybe it comes down to "I don't think there is a point in writing a new driver for review types, when they generally appear in journals, but I would still like to be able to distinguish `@article`s and `@review`s - for filtering say")

Comment: @moewe Yes, but then I'd expect it to apply `@article` formatting to `@review` entries. This way, it is using `@book`.

Comment: It isn't actually using `@book`, it uses the default, which happens to coincide with what `@book` looks like. From what I have seen, using the formatting of the aliased type would actually take some overhaul of the code.

Comment: @moewe True. But the code is annotated with a comment saying it is for `@book` in at least one case.

Comment: @cfr I knew, I should have cut that comment when copying it. `;-)` I saw that as well, I *think* that is an awkward way to distinguish between the two `\bibstring{volume}` and `\bibstring{jourvolume}`. I am guessing what happened here, but I think it might have gone like this: Supporting a `@review` type seemed like a good idea and broadly it is similar to `@article` types. But when it came to `\DeclareFieldFormat` in the standard styles, `@review` was somewhat forgotten about because it is just an alias.

Comment: @cfr But I agree that "[On `@review`] Reviews of some other work. This is a more specific variant of the `@article` type. The standard styles will treat this entry type as an alias for `@article`." in the docs is *a bit* misleading from what we could just see.

Comment: @moewe Cutting it wouldn't have helped. I'd read the source line before you posted your answer ;).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), p. 126, `\DeclareBibliographyAlias{alias}{type}` does the following:

> If a bibliography driver covers more than one entry type, this command
>   may be used to define an alias where `entrytype` is the name of a
>   defined driver.

When you use `\DeclareBibliographyAlias{alias}{type}` what happens internally (see `biblatex2.sty`) is

```
\newrobustcmd*{\DeclareBibliographyAlias}[2]{%
  \csedef{blx@bbx@#1}{%
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname blx@bbx@#2\endcsname}}
```

So `\blx@bbx@alias` just expands to `\blx@bbx@type`. The command `\blx@bbx@<type>` is used when printing bibliography lists (and friends) and "calls" the driver declared via `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{type}`.

For all other purposes `biblatex` still knows the actual entry type. It is just that the driver is rerouted.

The differences you noted were due to different `\DeclareFieldFormat` directives. `@article` gets special handling, namely

```
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{#1}% volume of a journal
```

while `@review` doesn't and defaults to the standard

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1}% volume of a book
```

The formatting code is spread throughout `biblatex2.sty`. It mostly contains calls to `\blx@getformat`, which breaks down to a switch on a host of definitions of the form `abx@#2@\blx@imc@thefield{entrytype}@#4` (where here `#2` is a field "id" and `#4` a field name). Here we can see that the actual entry type is used for formatting.

All in all, `\DeclareBibliographyAlias` really only is an alias for bibliography purposes and actually even less: only for the driver, formatting is still done with the usual (non-aliased) type.

---

For full aliasing, a Biber sourcemapping such as the ones defined in `biblatex.def` would be more appropriate (abridged code from `biblatex.def`)

```
\DeclareDriverSourcemap[datatype=bibtex]{
  \map{
    \step[typesource=conference, typetarget=inproceedings]
    \step[typesource=electronic, typetarget=online]
    \step[typesource=www,        typetarget=online]
  }
}
```

Comment: (+1) Shouldn't the documentation explain this? Given that BibTeX also has aliases and, as far as I know, those do get the same formatting. And this seems not a great way for aliases to work. It would seem to me better for the aliased type to set the default formatting, with then the possibility of overriding it. This way, either you lose the possibility of distinguishing them completely or the default formatting is actually something completely different.

Comment: @cfr Mhhh, the docs aren't overly clear on that maybe, but it says about `\DeclareBibliographyAlias`: "If a bibliography driver covers more than one entry type, this command may be used to define an alias where `<entrytype>` is the name of a defined driver." We really only talk about the *driver* here, but of course one needs to know that the *driver* and formatting work independently.

Comment: I meant more that on page 13, for example, there is no indication that `alias` has a specific, technical meaning which differs from, say, the BibTeX one. And there is no link there to the documentation on `\DeclareBibliographyAlias`. The introduction to that section says the types will be treated as `@misc` entries by standard styles. Then the type explanation says the standard styles will treat `@review` as an alias for `@article`. I wouldn't expect to need to figure out the command used to set the alias and read its documentation in order to know this is not `alias` in the BibTeX sense ;).

Comment: Of course, I'm making assumptions. Why should it use `alias` as BibTeX does? But I think it a not altogether unnatural reading to expect an alias to behave in the same way. (A shell alias, say, does just what the thing aliased would do.) I should add: I know you are not responsible for Biblatex's documentation! I'm just wondering if I alone find this confusing :(.

Comment: @cfr I just referred to exactly that passage in my comment above and I agree, that one is a bit misleading. The passage about `@misc` is right though at least de facto, because `@misc` does not have special formatting and there should really be no difference in output there.

Comment: @cfr I'm not responsible, but those who are responsible are normally really responsive when it comes to requests such as this. If you have a good suggestion for them (either about a different wording in the documentation or a better implementation of the aliasing mechanism), you can give them a shout (though something about changing the docs is more easily done than a major re-haul of the formatting mechanism).

Answer (score 2):

[moewe has provided a great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268557/) to which I append this as a mere footnote, but I thought it might be useful to add details of the way I've now configured this for the `@review` type specifically.

In my `biblatex.cfg`, I added the following lines to configure the format of the `volume` and `title` fields. `volume` follows the format for `@article`; `title` follows that for `@suppperiodical`:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[review]{volume}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[review]{title}{#1}
```

Because I also have custom configuration of the `in:` macro for `@article` (from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10686/)), I also adjusted this code:

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10686/
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
    \ifentrytype{review}{}{% apply to @review entries, too
      \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

For the MWE in question (which lacks the `in:` modification), this produces:

[image: Revised Rodent References]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{article,
  author    =   {Mouse, A.},
  title     =   {A Tall Tail},
  journal   =   {Tales to Nibble By},
  pages     =   {1--9},
  volume    =   31,
  number    =   4,
  year      =   1989,
}
@review{review,
  author    =   {Vole, Adrian},
  title     =   {Review of \emph{Great Grasses}, by A. N. Other-Mouse},
  journal   =   {Tales to Nibble By},
  pages     =   {23--4},
  volume    =   32,
  number    =   2,
  year      =   1990
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat[review]{volume}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[review]{title}{#1}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure whether this is the best way to format the titles of reviews. (I realise it depends on the style.) But neither book-type formatting nor article-type seemed quite right.