# remap biblatex entry type software to "online" driver

Tags: biblatex, biber

The biblatex manual states that the entry type "software" usually doesn't have a driver and falls back to "misc" as its driver. With the IEEE style this doesn't print URLs. Therefore: is there any way to remap software to use the "online" driver as its fallback?

Comment: Do you really use `biblatex` and the `biblatex-ieee` style? In an example I got to see the URL for a `software` entry. Maybe you can show an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that a post-processing step of my bib file converts every `url` tag to `link`. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{software}{online}
```

to use the `@online` driver for `@software` types. You can learn a bit more about this command in [What exactly is the relationship Biblatex refers to as an alias of an entry type? And how should the formatting of aliased entry types be configured?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/268553/35864)