# How to silence "No driver for entry type" warnings?

Tags: biblatex, warnings

I have the following warning:

```
Package biblatex Warning: No driver for entry type 'artwork'.
```

I have deduced from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434281/183394) that it is being treated as `misc`, and I am fine with that. However, I wish to get rid of the warning and have no idea how to do so. How do I?

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325255

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325255/183394) to a similar question has the solution:

```
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{artwork}{misc}
```