# Silence biber warning "Invalid field 'XXX' for entrytype 'YYY'"

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have created a few aliases of bibliography types, e.g. `standard` is a `report` or `software` is `online`. Now, when using such types in my bib file and enabled `--validate-datamodel`, I get warnings like:

> Datamodel: Entry 'Spread' (thesis.bib): Invalid field 'url' for entrytype 'software'

How can I make biber happy about this again? Any way to enhance the data model for the aliases?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@standard{RFC4627,
 date = {2006},
 editor = {IETF},
 number = {4627},
 title = {The application/json Media Type for {JavaScript} Object Notation ({JSON})},
 type = {RFC},
 url = {http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt},
 urldate = {2016-09-08}
}

@software{Spread,
 label = {Spread},
 title = {The Spread Toolkit},
 url = {http://www.spread.org/},
 urldate = {2016-09-08}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyAlias{software}{online}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{standard}{report}
\bibliography{test}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography{}
    % should still work
    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,type=software,title={Lis‌​t of Software Packages}]{}
\end{document}
```

Compiled using latexmk with the following `latexmkrc`:

```
$pdf_mode = 1;
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode';

$biber = 'biber --validate-datamodel %O %S';
```

Comment: As explained in [What exactly is the relationship Biblatex refers to as an alias of an entry type? And how should the formatting of aliased entry types be configured?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/268553/35864) the relation defined by `\DeclareBibliographyAlias` is in a way on the fly for `biblatex`. Biber does not know about it, in particular Biber's data model has no way of knowing about it and so it doesn't validate. You can use sourcemapping as described in the end of my answer for a 'Biber-proof' aliasing.

Comment: @moewe, Thanks, this silences the warnings. However, now I cannot address entries of the mapped types anymore, e.g. for selective bibliographies like `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,type=software,title={List of Software Packages}]{}`. This list is empty now and instead software ends up in the normal bibliography, which I filter as `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,nottype=software]{}`. Any way to make this work again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [What exactly is the relationship BibLaTeX refers to as an alias of an entry type? And how should the formatting of aliased entry types be configured?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/268553/35864) the alias defined by `\DeclareBibliographyAlias` is only for bibliography driver purposes. The alias is only accessible for `biblatex`. In particular Biber does not know about it.

You could do

```
\DeclareDriverSourcemap[datatype=bibtex]{
  \map{
    \pertype{software}
    \step[typesource=software, typetarget=online, final]
    \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,type:software}, append]
  }
  \map{
    \pertype{standard}
    \step[typesource=standard, typetarget=report, final]
    \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,type:standard}, append]
  }
}
```

This will remap `@software` to `@online` and `@standard` to `@report` for all intents and purposes (so you can't select by `type` any more). To remedy this, we add keywords that give the former type with the keyword `type:<type>`.

Now your filtering is not `type=<type>`, but `keyword = {type:<type>}`, i.e.

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, keyword=type:software],
```

instead of `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, type=software]`.

Comment: Do I need to change anything to the filtered `printbibliography` calls after adding the keywords? Right now this still doesn't work.

Comment: @languitar Why yes of course. Now you don't do `type=standard`, but you do `keyword=type:standard` (the rest analogue).

Comment: Ok, getting closer, However, some publications of my original document (and I really can't find a pattern) now end up in the software list instead of the normal bibliography. Even with completely different entry types and there are no keywords defined on them.

Comment: @languitar Sorry, I will need an example for that.

Comment: Some examples: https://gist.github.com/languitar/274a9fb522255cd293a8fbeaeec048fa. Could it be that adding the keywords needs to be restricted with `pertype`?

Comment: Ok, adding `\pertype{software}` and `\pertype{standard}` to the respective maps solves the issue.

Comment: @languitar I just checked with the examples you showed. With my earlier code (which I amended to include the `final`) I do not need the `\pertype` restriction. An example in the `biblatex` documentation also suggests it is not necessary. Can you please check if you can leave out the `\pertype` if you have the `final`?