# BibLaTeX warning: No driver for entry type ''

Tags: biblatex, warnings

I'm getting this bizarre warning when using `biber` 2.14 (`biblatex` 3.14).

```
Package biblatex Warning: No driver for entry type ''.
(biblatex)                Using fallback driver on input line 131.
```

Line 131 reads: `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]`

How is this possible? My bibliography file was created with BibDesk and is valid.

Comment: What version of `biblatex` and Biber are you using? Do you use a custom data model? There were some changes to the entry field/type name normalisation in recent Biber updates that might have caused something like this. But I thought that was resolved. Is there any chance you can show us a small, yet fully compilable example document that reproduces the warning (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)?

Comment: Ah, the issue I thought about is not fixed in Biber v2.14 yet. It's https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/299 (inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/520657/35864). Do you use an entry type that is not defined in the standard data model?

Comment: Since you are running Biber 2.14 it could be the issue mentioned in my last comment. But we can only say that with certainty if you can show us a document and `.bib` entry that reproduce the warning. Any chance you could cobble something together?

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction. It was indeed a problem caused by a non-standard entry type. I will add an answer for further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by moewe, this warning occurs when using an undefined entry type in the `.bib` file.

In my case, I updated to TeX Live 2020 some time after creating the `.bib` file; a part of that update was that the APA style for `biblatex` got updated to comply with the 7th edition. I was using `@newsarticle` in my bibliography, but this entry type has been removed in the latest version of `biblatex-apa`. Hence, the warning.

In case anyone wants to use `@newsarticle` regardless: `\usepackage[style=apa6]{biblatex}` or something similar should do the trick.

Better yet: Use `@article` instead, and replace the field `newspaper` with `journal`.