# \DeclareBibliographyAlias is not working

Tags: biblatex, bibentry

After moving to a vanilla TeXLive according to [Slike's indications](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/154737), I can no longer print a bibliography including only entries of a type that I have declared with `\DeclareBibliographyAlias`. Consider, for instance, the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyAlias{course}{book}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{martin,
    author      = {Martin, Andrew},
    title       = {History of Robots},
}
@course{olivaw,
    author      = {Olivaw, Daneel},
    title       = {How to manipulate humans and not die in the attempt},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[title=Books, type=book]

\printbibliography[title=Courses, type=course]

\end{document}
```

Where the log file is [txt.do/1fg2y](http://txt.do/1fg2y), the output returned is:

[image]

But it should clearly be:

[image]

But when I just pass one `\printbibliography` without options, it sort of reconises my `@course` entry, since the output is:

[image]

However, it still gives the alert:

> No driver for entry type ''.

#### Note on possible duplicate

This is not a duplicate of [kaba's question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520657/declarebibliographyalias-stopped-working-in-biblatex-3-14) since the issue of `\DeclareBibliographyAlias` was not the main problem nor is it given an answer to what I'm asking here.

Comment: imho the answer you are linking too address your problem: @course is not a declared entry type, if you want to use it you will have to add it to the datamodel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying cause of the problem here is definitely the same as in [\DeclareBibliographyAlias stopped working in biblatex 3.14](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/520657/35864): Biber 2.14 produces an empty entry type field for types not known to the data model. That is arguably a bug and will be resolved in Biber 2.15. See https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/299.

---

In [\DeclareBibliographyAlias stopped working in biblatex 3.14](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/520657/35864) it was pretty clear that the use of `\DeclareBibliographyAlias` was superfluous and it could easily be argued that the following use of `\DeclareBibliographyDriver` for an entry type not declared in the data model is not supported.

Here, things are a bit more difficult. Before we start [What exactly is the relationship Biblatex refers to as an alias of an entry type? And how should the formatting of aliased entry types be configured?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/268553/35864) contains some background about what `\DeclareBibliographyAlias` does and does not do (it also explains what we mean with 'hard' and 'soft' aliases).

Essentially you are calling

```
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{<alias>}{<entrytype>}
```

for an entry type `<alias>` that is not defined in the data model.

One could probably argue for and against this being supported use of `\DeclareBibliographyAlias` and it is probably possible to find bits and pieces of the `biblatex` documentation that can be read as supporting either argument.

I'd probably be inclined to side with those saying that this isn't supported use and that the `<alias>` in `\DeclareBibliographyAlias{<alias>}{<entrytype>}` needs to be declared with the data model first, but it definitely is not worth starting a fight about this.

The matter of the fact **at the moment** is that `\DeclareBibliographyAlias{<alias>}{<entrytype>}` will only work if `<alias>` is declared in the data model, so currently there are two ways to make things work again.

1. Instead of the soft alias from `\DeclareBibliographyAlias` declare a hard alias with a Biber sourcemap.
2. Declare `@course` in the data model.

**Solution 1** will map `@course` to `@book` for all intents and purposes, so you wouldn't be able to filter by `type` easily any more. You could work around that using `subtype`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyAlias{course}{book}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{   
    \map{
      \step[typesource=course,     typetarget=book, final]
      \step[fieldset=entrysubtype, fieldvalue=course]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{martin,
    author      = {Martin, Andrew},
    title       = {History of Robots},
}
@course{olivaw,
    author      = {Olivaw, Daneel},
    title       = {How to manipulate humans and not die in the attempt},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Books, type=book, notsubtype=course]
\printbibliography[title=Courses, subtype=course]
\end{document}
```

**Solution 2** involves defining a custom `.dbx` file that makes `@course` know to `biblatex`. Since you alias `@course` to `@book` I just took the field declarations for `@book` from [blx-dm.def (link to the current version on CTAN)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/latex/blx-dm.def) (you can find the path of the file installed on your machine by typing `kpsewhich blx-dm.def` in the command line).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{course.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{course.dbx}[2020/08/11 biblatex datamodel extension for @course type]
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{course}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[course]{
  author,
  addendum,
  afterword,
  annotator,
  chapter,
  commentator,
  edition,
  editor,
  editora,
  editorb,
  editorc,
  editortype,
  editoratype,
  editorbtype,
  editorctype,
  eid,
  foreword,
  introduction,
  isbn,
  language,
  location,
  maintitle,
  maintitleaddon,
  mainsubtitle,
  note,
  number,
  origlanguage,
  pages,
  pagetotal,
  part,
  publisher,
  pubstate,
  series,
  subtitle,
  title,
  titleaddon,
  translator,
  volume,
  volumes}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, datamodel=course]{biblatex}


\DeclareBibliographyAlias{course}{book}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{martin,
    author      = {Martin, Andrew},
    title       = {History of Robots},
}
@course{olivaw,
    author      = {Olivaw, Daneel},
    title       = {How to manipulate humans and not die in the attempt},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Books, type=book]
\printbibliography[title=Courses, type=course]
\end{document}
```

In both cases you get the desired output

[image: Two bibliographies with one entry each: One for books, one for courses.]