# Adding white space arround pages tag in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to know if it is possible to add white spaces around the dash sign in page range in bibliography list.

That's what I have:

```
S. 1234-1235
```

That's what I want to have:

```
S. 1234 - 1235
```

In my bib-file the pages tag includes white spaces:

```
pages = {1234 -- 1235}
```

That is my minimal bib file:

```
@article{IJAMT,
         author        = {Author},
         title         = {Title},
         journaltitle  = {Journal},
         year          = {2016},
         volume        = {69},
         number        = {9 -- 12},
         pages         = {2315 -- 2321},
         label         = {REF}
```

And here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,bibencoding=utf8,hyperref=true,sorting=anyt,    natbib=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}

% Own Style for Articles
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \printnames{author}:\newunit%
  \printfield{title}.\newunit%
  \printfield{journaltitle}{ }\printfield{volume}{ }%
  (\printfield{year}){ }\printfield{number},\newunit%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \finentry}

\bibliography{literature/bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{IJAMT}
  \newpage
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. To give a correct answer without a complete MWE is difficult.  I guess, you could enter the page range in your BibTeX-file as `1234~-~1235` although I am convinced, that it is typographically incorrect.

Comment: That does not work.

Comment: Please give us more details and save us from having to type everything on our own.

Comment: jan is asking about an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).That is the easiest and most efficient way to tell us how exactly you create your bibliography - a solution will most likely depend on the packages and styles you use.

Comment: Do you use `biblatex` as your tagging suggests or BibTeX as the title suggests?

Comment: I use biblatex. I changed the title.

Comment: Note that your redefinition of the `@article` driver is a bit rough. You should never have a literal `:` or `(` in the driver definition.

Comment: What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include an alternative to your redefinition of the `@article` driver.

Answer (score 6):

We just need to redefine `\bibrangedash` to add the space

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \renewrobustcmd*{\bibrangedash}{\addspace\textendash\space}}
```

Since `\bibrangedash` is a language-specific command, we need to redefine it within `\DefineBibliographyExtras{<lang>}` where `<lang>` is your document language.

Instead of `\addspace\textendash\space` you could also use thin spaces and prevent a line break before the dash by using

```
\addnbthinspace\textendash\penalty\hyphenpenalty\addthinspace
```

instead.

---

BTW: You instead of redefining your `@article` driver in the way you did, you could use

```
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}
```

to achieve a similar thing. Plus maybe [Suppress “In:” biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864). You should not have literal punctuation in your driver, always use `\setunit` and friends together with `\addcomma` and friends or put the formatting into `\DeclareFieldFormat`.

Comment: Doesn't this add feasible break points before and after the dash?

Comment: @egreg So it does. Do you think that is undesirable? Would you prefer `\renewrobustcmd*{\bibrangedash}{\addnbspace\textendash\addnbspace}`?

Comment: If a space must be, I'd prefer it thinner and not flexible; breaking before the dash is obviously not a choice, after it might help in tough situation.

Comment: What is the main advantage using `\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}` instead redefining `@article` ?

Comment: @Micha The standard `@article` driver contains many things that can be controlled via options, your redefinition kills almost all or these options and uses some other crude techniques such as hard-coded punctuation. For what you want it is only necessary to redefine `journal+issuetitle` (this macro is used in the driver for `@article`) since that is the only part of the article driver that needs to be changed.