# Adding a specific text in a bibliography line

Tags: biblatex

**Writing a text in a bibliography line.**

I'm using `biblatex`, the name of the bibliography file is `example.bib`. The work that I want to edit is the following:

```
@article{Example-article,
title={Example},
author={Someone},
journal={arXiv-somenumber},
year={2017}
}
```

this prints "In: arXiv-somenumber" in the bibliography but I want to add a text before "arXiv-somenumber" showing that the work is "to appear".

I tried to use `note{}` but when I use this option, the "In: arXiv-somenumber" text disappears.

The exist some solution?

This is my code

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{example.bib}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{theoremref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{amstext}

\begin{document}

    \cite{Example-article}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Moreover I want this that text for only that specific citation

Comment: Are you using `biblatex`? A MWE would be appreciated...

Comment: As your example demonstrates, it is not the `.bib` entry that is the cause of your problem, but something else. The obvious culprit is the package responsible for typesetting the bibliography, but it is unclear how you are getting your `.bib` entries typeset. Until you provide more information (and please make it an MWE), no one can answer your question except by chance.

Comment: What text? Is the title of the journal really `arXiv-somenumber`? Because, if not, your entry shouldn't claim it is. Please edit your code to make it *minimal*. Only include the packages required to reproduce the issue. Also, avoid loading packages twice. It makes for trouble.

Comment: Not quite a minimal example for two reasons: (1) no `\documentclass` line; and (2) many of those packages have absolutely nothing to do with bibliographies or your specific problem. However, I think [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10686/8528) is what you are looking for. (I also endorse all of cfr's recommendations.)

Comment: @jon I had imagined that the OP wanted to add something to just this entry rather than all cases in which an entry is 'in' something. But it isn't very clear, now I think about it, from the question.

Comment: @cfr -- hmm, I think what's clear is that I clearly didn't read the question carefully. However, depending on what this mysterious bit of text is, that answer is certainly one way to add text before whatever is put in the `journal`|`journaltitle` field. (It is also probably not the best way to do it for most purposes, but I agree that the question requires some clarification.)

Comment: @MiguelRomán -- Could you also explain what it is you want to add? Is it a standard piece of text for all entry types that will have an `In: ` in the output (e.g., `@article`, `@incollection`)? Is it just for journals? Or is it only for certain entries?

Comment: @jon  I want to write "Exp. Math. To appear" before the "In : ...."

Comment: @MiguelRomán -- Do you want that string to appear before *every* entry that has `In :` in the citation? If so, then look at my above link. If not, the criteria by which `biblatex` decides to print that string needs to be explained further.

Comment: @jon I want it only for that specific citation

Comment: If just for a specific citation, then don't use BibTeX but Biber: `\usepackage[..., backend=biber, ...]{biblatex}`. If that's possible for you, I can show one way to do it.

Comment: But I'm citing other papers. But there is only one that I want to add that specific text

Comment: `@article` is simply not the right entry type if you don't know the journal just yet: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415115/35864

Answer (score 1):

`biblatex` provides the `pubstate` field to specify information such as `to appear`.  So you can write the entry as

```
@Article{Example-article,
  title =    {Example},
  author =   {Someone, X.},
  journaltitle = {J. Jour.},
  year =     2017,
  pubstate =     {to appear},
  eprinttype =   {arxiv},
  eprint =   {1008.2849}
}
```

(note the use of `eprint...` fields for specifying the preprint version).

You may want to adjust the standard placement of this field in the print output as in the following example:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{example.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \printfield{issue}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}
    \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
    \printfield{pubstate}}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit}

\begin{document}

\cite{Example-article}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

By default the pubstate information is printed by the biblatex macro `addendum+pubstate`.  The adjustments above remove the printing from the pubstate from that macro and move it to the `issue+date` macro.   You may want to restrict this adjustment to only articles or some other class of publications.  If [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/15925) does not help you with that, then please ask a new question.