# Format of @article without journal title field in biblatex bibliography entries

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

This question is similar to [Suppress “In:” biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682) and [biblatex: How to remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12254), but I don’t want to change the format of bibliography entries completely, but would rather like it to deal better with some cases.

If I have a BibTeX entry of type `@article` which does not give a journal title (e. g. in the `journal` field), as it happens with pure e-print articles, the entry is still printed of the form “In: (<year>)” in the bibliography.

For example, with [this BibTeX entry](https://inspirehep.net/record/1637592/export/hx), the entry is printed as follows in the bibliography:

> D. Wegman. “Deviations of exact neutrino textures using radiative
>   neutrino masses”. In: (2017). arXiv: 1711.08004 [hep-ph].

The part “In: (2017).” looks very suboptimal. How could the formatting be improved for entries without a journal title?

Comment: This is not an `@article` entry. It is an `@online`. See the arXiv-only examples in `biblatex-examples.bib`. `@article` is only for papers published in a journal, `@article`s *always* have a `journal` (and `volume`). If a paper does not have a `journal` that means it was not published in a journal and so `@article` is inappropriate

Comment: To echo @moewe's comment: If an entry is lacking a `journal` field, the entry shouldn't be given the type `@article`. Period.

Comment: I see. So I suppose the fault lies with the BibTeX output at INSPIRE-HEP.

Comment: It is a possibility: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/105447

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/411073/105447

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The entry type `@article` is only for papers that were actually published in a journal. `@article`s *must* always have a `journal` (and `volume`) field. That means that if an entry was not published in a journal and consequently has no `journal` field, it cannot be an `@article`.

arXiv preprints that are not yet published in a journal are normally classified as `@online` entries. Compare the entries `baez/online`, `itzhaki` and `wassenberg` in `biblatex-examples.bib`. You could go with

```
@online{wegman,
  author       = {Wegman, D.},
  title        = {Deviations of Exact Neutrino Textures Using Radiative Neutrino Masses},
  date         = {2017-11-21},
  version      = 1,
  eprinttype   = {arxiv},
  eprint       = {1711.08004},
  eprintclass  = {hep-ph},
}
```

There is no reason to believe that not choosing `@article` and using `@online` instead somehow demotes the source to a second-class citation. Choosing entry types is not about "rating" the source, it is about picking the correct framework to fit in the publication data.

There might be a general sentiment that online sources are generally less reliable or less citable (is that even a word?), but the entry type in a `.bib` should not be seen as an indicator to assess this. If you absolutely can't live with `@online` go for `@misc` instead.

I will admit that the advent of online publishing may have blurred the lines between periodicals/journals and pre-print servers. And it might be hard to come up with a good definition of what a journals is now. Nevertheless I think that the arXiv is not a journal.

Comment: I disagree. *arXiv* should be considered as a journal, in this sense. Its pre-print status can optionally be indicated with: `pubstate = {\bibstring{prepublished}}`. There is no need to consider pre-prints as second-class objects, especially for citation purposes.

Comment: @CobyViner There is no indication that not choosing `@article` as entry types somehow demotes the status of a source or diminishes its significance - let alone turns it into a second-class object! Picking the right entry type is not about "rating" a source, it is about choosing the right framework for the data. And I maintain that the arXiv is not a (scientific) journal with volumes, pages and hence not really appropriate here. After all you would not try to stuff a `@book` into an `@article`...

Comment: I disagree on both points. And it is worth noting that many peer-reviewed journals themselves are online-only and lack volumes, having a page number in the same fashion as *arXiv* (that is an article number alone). Especially given the difficulty that still remains in citing pre-prints in some journals (for economic, and not scientific reasons), it is worth considering the impact that citing them as `@online` might have. But regardless, I really do think that they are an `@article` in every sense and their `journal` is simply `"arXiv"`.

Comment: @CobyViner You are certainly right that the advent of online publishing and online-only publishing has made it harder to pin down whether or not a publication is a 'journal'. For what it is worth I think it is absurd to imply that not choosing `@article` would demote a source: To circumvent that I could simply invent my own journal to obtain promotion to `@article`. The entry type `@article` does not grant a higher status than `@online` by itself - what you or other people read into it is a different matter.

Comment: My main point is that *arXiv* should be considered as an `@article`, in every sense. Its citations should follow the usual format for any journal. And I do not think the suggestion is absurd—it is fundamentally about the nature of pre-prints, not about relative "status" of citation types in any overall sense. It seems we will have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @CobyViner My point is that for the purpose of `biblatex` (BibTeX) entry types the choice of `@article` for papers on the arXiv is suboptimal. I am basing my opinion purely on concerns about the `biblatex`/BibTeX data model and my understanding of that model and its semantics, not on anything else. I don't think it is absurd to want to treat arXiv preprints as `@article`, what I consider absurd is the idea that not using `@article` turns a citation into a second-class object.