# If Statements in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, xifthen

Having spent many hours poring over examples and documentation, I have finally got my references almost up to what I require (yay!). There are still a few bits that I cannot manage, and I'm hoping that you titans of TeX will be able to assist! :) At the bottom I've given a 'minimal' working example... but it's not that short, so I'm going to try to summarise some of the issues here. Mostly it boils down to desiring `if/then` statements. Possibly I need to use `xifthen`? (I'm using `DeclareBibliographyDriver`.)

(1) Some of my items have volume and issue numbers. In this case, I'd like to write these as "**Volume**.Issue", eg **3**.2. I've done this using `\printfield{volume}\addperiod\printfield{number}`. This is fine when there is a volume and issue number, but when there isn't it prints a fullstop (.), which I don't want. So I'd like to say

```
\printfield{volume}
if {'number' exists (as a field)} then {\addperiod\printfield{number}}
```

Similarly, I'd like to print the page numbers in brackets, eg (112--114). Again, I can use `\printtext[parens]{\printfield{pages}}`, but when there aren't any page numbers this just gives an empty pair of brackets, (), which I don't want. So I'd like to say

```
if {'pages' exists} then {\printtext[parens]{\printfield{pages}}}
```

I appreciate that the usual thing is not to have two questions in the same post, but given how similar these are, and that they should (hopefully) be able to both be answered together, I felt it was best to put them like this.

---

I now give a MWE, and a snapshot of the output.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{FR:giant-mixing,
    title = {The Evolution of the Mixing Rate of a Simple Random Walk on the Giant Component of a Random Graph},
    volume = {33},
    number = {1},
    journaltitle = {Random Structures \& Algorithms},
    urldate = {2018-03-22},
    date = {2008-05-12},
    pages = {68-86},
    author = {Fountoulakis, Nikolaos and Reed, Bruce A.}
}
@article{AGHH:dynamic-cm,
    archivePrefix = {arXiv},
    eprinttype = {arxiv},
    eprint = {1606.07639},
    title = {Mixing Times of Random Walks on Dynamic Configuration Models},
    date = {2016-06-24},
    author = {Avena, Luca and G{\"u}lda{\c s}, Hakan and van der Hofstad, Remco and den Hollander, Frank},
    options = {useprefix=true}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[hyperref=true,backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat
    [article,book]
    {volume}{\textbf{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
    {pages}{#1}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
    \printnames{author}%
\   \newblock
    \printtext[parens]{\printfield{year}}\addperiod%
    \newunit
    \printfield{title}
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{journaltitle}%
    \printfield{eprint}%\addperiod%
\   \newblock
    \printfield{volume}\addperiod\printfield{number}%
\   \newblock
    \printtext[parens]{\printfield{pages}}%
}


\begin{document}

Document...

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I assume the `\ ` in the code are copy-and-paste artefacts and not intended, is that correct?

Comment: You have `\iffieldundef` to test for empty fields (and equivalent for lists and names). But, in your case, it seems the punctuation tracker may do the job with `\printfield{volume}\setunit*{\adddot}\printfield{number}` (untested).

Comment: @moewe -- they're for spacing. Is it not good practice to use them in such a way?

Comment: As for the `pages` field, I'd say a formating directive would probably be the more adequate.

Comment: @gusbrs -- that indeed does work; I really have no idea why, but it has removed the `.` at the end of the first reference. \\ What is a formatting directive? =P

Comment: You can determine the format of a field when printed with `\DeclareFieldFormat` (and equivalents). That should spare you the conditional and would be more in line with good practice, I think. (Rather than hard code it in your bibdriver).

Comment: As to why that works, the starred version of `\setunit` only does anything if the last `\print` actually prints something. So, if no volume, no dot. :)

Comment: @moewe, if you'd like to answer, please do so. I can only come back to this in detail in about half an hour.

Comment: Oh, yeah, so I just replace my `\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}` with `\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{(#1)}`, and that is working fine! :)

Comment: @gusbrs I'll start to write an answer, maybe you can overtake me if you start in half an hour...

Comment: As far as I can tell, you have answered all of my questions, so no need to write a long answer! If you wish, you can summarise what you wrote, or if you prefer I can do that :) -- thank you very much :)

Comment: I'd like to write a comprehensive answer because I feel that a few things you do go against the spirit of `biblatex`.

Comment: Ok, for sure, thank you very much for your time and effort! :)

Comment: @moewe I wish! The day I can overtake you at anything biblatex-related, I'll consider myself "graduated". :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`biblatex` has several conditionals available. Amongst them is `\iffieldundef{<field>}` to check if a field is undefined (a field is usually undefined if it is empty). So you *could* use

```
\iffieldundef{number}
  {}%                              <- do nothing if number does not exist
  {\addperiod\printfield{number}}% <- number exists: print it
```

---

I feel, however, that in your case you don't actually need `\iffieldundef`. Instead you will want to have a look at two very important concepts of `biblatex` styles

- field formats `\DeclareFieldFormat` and
- the punctuation tracker

Let's take `\printtext[parens]{\printfield{pages}}` as an example: You want to print the page number in parentheses. But as you have noticed this line of code actually gives you an empty pair of round brackets if the `pages` field is empty. That is because `\printtext[parens]` will simply wrap its argument in round brackets, even if it is empty. With our `\iffieldundef` you cold write `\iffieldundef{pages}{}{\printtext[parens]{\printfield{pages}}}`. But there is a more elegant way:

Define that you want to see the `pages` of `@article`s in round brackets with

```
 \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
```

and then simply use

```
 \printfield{pages}
```

With the first line you tell `biblatex` to put the page numbers in parentheses and the second line tells `biblatex` to print the page numbers. If the `pages` field is not present nothing happens.

Something similar could be done for the year, but `biblatex` has a more complex set-up to handle dates, so that is slightly more involved. I would probably go with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{date}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
```

for the format and then `\printdate` or better

```
\usebibmacro{date}
```

The punctuation tracker makes it much easier to take care of punctuation and spaces. You won't have to use `\iffieldundef` for the dot between `volume` and `number`, and you won't have to use `\` to provide space.

The tracker is explained in §4.11.7 *Using the Punctuation Tracker* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf). The section is a few pages long (so is this answer ...), but it comes with many examples and is definitely worth a read. The idea of the punctuation tracker is that `biblatex` does not immediately print any punctuation it encounters, instead it remembers the punctuation and inserts it when it prints text the next time. This avoids double punctuation. The first takeaway from the section is that you will almost always want to use `\setunit` for punctuation, punctuation commands should only rarely appear outside of `\setunit`.

`\setunit` takes the supplied punctuation command and saves it in the punctuation buffer. The buffer is used and cleared the next time `biblatex` prints anything (using `\print...`). Subsequent `\setunit`s overwrite the buffer.

So you could say

```
\printfield{eprint}%
\setunit{\addspace}\newblock
\printfield{pages}%
```

to print the `eprint` field followed by a space and then the `pages` field. You won't run into trouble if one of the two fields is not printed.

The go-to punctuation between two fields is `\newunit\newblock`. `\newunit` essentially does a `\setunit` on the punctuation defined in `\newunitpunct` and `\newblock` adds an internal marker that a new block/'chunk' starts here. The behaviour of blocks can be modified with the `block` option.

Using the punctuation tracker `\printfield{volume}\addperiod\printfield{number}%` would become

```
\printfield{volume}%
\setunit*{\adddot}
\printfield{number}%
```

Here we used the starred version `\setunit*`, it only inserts a value into the buffer if the last `\print...` command before it did anything (so it is like `\setunit` with an added check: If the last `\print...` printed anything, `\setunit*` behaves exactly like `\setunit`, otherwise it discards its argument). So no dot will be inserted into the buffer if `volume` is empty.

---

If you write bibliography drivers it is a good idea to try and model them on the standard drivers found in `standard.bbx`. The drivers in `standard.bbx` don't actually call many `\print...` directives directly, instead they call other bibmacros to do this. A driver should always call the two macros `bibindex` and `begentry` at the beginning and *must* call `finentry` at the end. The `finentry` bibmacro calls the `\finentry` macro that does some clean-up work.

Your set-up could look like

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{date}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{journaltitle}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{eprint}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \printfield{pages}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
```

In fact this could have been changed to resemble the `@article` driver in `standard.bbx` even more, but then more things would have been hidden.

In fact I believe that you can get the output you want without even redefining a single driver only by changing bibmacros and a bit of sly trickery.

---

Let me close with a few of my favourite `biblatex` pet peeves

- The option `hyperref=true` is normally not better than the default `hyperref=auto`. The only difference between the two is that `hyperref=true` writes a warning to the `.log` file if `hyperref` is not loaded. Other than that they behave identical. In particular both enable hyperlinking if and only if `hyperref` is loaded.
- A paper that was published on the arXiv but not in any journal is not an `@article` - it is an `@online` entry. Only papers that actually have a non-empty `journal` field can be `@article`s. See [Format of @article without journal title field in biblatex bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415115/35864)

Comment: Thanks very much for your very thorough response! I do have a couple of questions, which I'll put in individual comments for ease of reading.

Comment: When I do **Volume**.Number, you said to use the stared `\setunit`, because this only prints the `\addperiod` if the previous `\print` actually did something. How come if I have an bibitem with a Volume entry but no Number entry then it doesn't print the fullstop? The **Volume** prints, so surely then the fullstop (period) is printed under `\setunit*`? Do you mean instead that the `\setunit*` only prints if the *next* one actually prints?

Comment: @SamT My description of `\setunit*` might not have been clear enough, sorry, I have edited the answer with slightly more detail. If you have a volume, but no number, `\setunit*` adds its punctuation to the buffer (it acts like `\setunit`, because the last `\print...` actually printed something), but before the buffer is inserted the next `\setunit` overwrites the buffer and so you get to see a period and a space. Because the buffer is overwritten, the last `\setunit`/`\newunit` before a `\print...` wins.