# Why are my inline citations showing up as the 'nickname' of the reference rather than author year style?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

EDIT: There was a pst suggested in the comments, but I have gone through it and tried to understand how the answers relate to my typeset code. I am still at a loss for how what I have done is wrong.

I am looking for inline citations as 'author year' style, however they are coming up by the nickname. For instance, in my references list I have

```
 @article{main,
title = {Fraisse Limits, Ramsey Theory, and Topological Dynamics of Automorphism Groups},
author = {A.S. Kechris, V.G. Pestov, S. Todorcevic},
journal = {arXiv:math/0305241v4 [math.LO]},
year = {2004}
}
```

and when I write the following in overleaf:

```
Theorems from \cite{main} seen as essential to the main result are pretty much quoted verbatim.
```

It shows as

> Theorems from [**main**] seen as essential to the main result are pretty much quoted verbatim.

rather than with author year. In fact, my references list is not exhibiting either.

I suspect it has to do with the warning I have just noticed next to my `\printbibliography` in my control file, which says 'warning, empty bibliography' when I however over it. Yet I have no idea why. My full control page is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}


\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\title{\textbf{Meep}}



\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents


\subfile{introduction.tex}
\subfile{f1.tex}
\subfile{f2.tex}
\subfile{AppendixA.tex}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: The input `author = {A.S. Kechris, V.G. Pestov, S. Todorcevic},` is wrong. Multiple names *must always* be separated with `and` regardless of the desired output, so the correct input would be `author = {A.S. Kechris and V.G. Pestov and S. Todorcevic},`. (In *this* particular case the wrong input will not cause an error, but if you have other works with more than three authors that use the wrong input format, Biber may error and give up on your citations.) You may have to clear the Overleaf cache after you fix the error in the `.bib` file: https://de.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache

Comment: Unrelated to the actual problem, but I wouldn't use `@article` for a paper that was only published on the arXiv: Use `@online` and move the arXiv identifier from the `journal` field to `eprint` and `eprinttype`: `eprinttype = {arxiv}, eprint = {math/0305241v4}, eprintclass = {math.LO},` See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415115/35864.

Comment: [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/134144) might be helpful.

Comment: @leandriis I have gone through the suggested post, but am still struggling to figure out concretely how to fix the issue. The answers help me to understand how the process occurs heuristically, but I still do not see what the error is in what I have written

Comment: After having corrected the  errors moewe pointed out in a previous comment, did you run `biber` on your .tex file?

Comment: @leandriis At the top I have `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}` which I thought runs biber

Comment: Have you corrected the wrong `author` field? On Overleaf Biber will run automatically for you. (You may have to clear the cache to avoid errors.)

Comment: Overleaf may run biber for you, but on a local installation you have to press a special button. Please take a look at https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Answer (score 1):

Some comments and observations (some of which have already been made in earlier comments):

- If you want authoryear-style citation callouts, don't specify `style=alphabetic` while loading `biblatex`. Instead, use either `style=authoryear` or some style (e.g., `apa` and `apa6`) that generates authoryear-style citation callouts.
- Individual authors in the `author` field *must* be separated by the keyword `and`.
- The entry type `@article` should be used exclusively for pieces published in scholarly academic journals. For your entry, use either the catch-all entry type `@misc` or the newer, biblatex-only entry type `@online` and replace `journal = {arXiv:math/0305241v4 [math.LO]}` with `url = {https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0305241.pdf}`.
- In the `title` field, do please replace `Fraisse` with either `Fraïssé` or -- if your keyboard setup doesn't allow the direct entry of the characters `ï` and `é` -- `Fra{\"i}ss{\'e}`.
- Load the `xurl` package to facilitate the typesetting of URL strings in a way that allows problem-free line breaking.
- Last but not least, don't forget to run `biber` after adding or changing `\cite`-type instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{ref.bib}
@online{kpt:04,
title  = {Fraïssé Limits, {Ramsey} Theory, and 
          Topological Dynamics of Automorphism Groups},
author = {A. S. Kechris and V. G. Pestov and S. Todorcevic},
url    = {https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0305241.pdf},
year   = 2004
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
Theorems from \citet{kpt:04} seen as essential to the 
main result are pretty much quoted verbatim.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```