# ACM bibtex format for arXiv papers

Tags: bibliographies, acm

I use the ACM [format](https://www.acm.org/publications/authors/bibtex-formatting) to print arXiv papers with the following example

```
\documentclass[manuscript,screen]{acmart}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Text~\cite{Mnih13}

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sample-base}


\end{document}
\endinput
```

And the entry is

```
@article{Mnih13,
  author    = {V. Mnih and K. Kavukcuoglu and D. Silver and A. Graves and I. Antonoglou and D. Wierstra and M. Riedmiller},
  title     = {Playing Atari with Deep Reinforcement Learning},
  year      = {2013},
  eprint = {arXiv:1312.5602},
}
```

Now, what I see in the output is

> V. Mnih, K. Kavukcuoglu, D. Silver, A. Graves, I. Antonoglou, D. Wierstra, and M. Riedmiller. 2013. Playing Atari with Deep Reinforcement Learning.(2013). arXiv:arXiv:1312.56021

So, I see two 2013 and two arXiv. Is that normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples on the site you cite in the question (https://www.acm.org/publications/authors/bibtex-formatting) seem to be outdated. The [documentation of the `acmart` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acmart/acmart.pdf) (to which `ACM-Reference-Format.bst` belongs) suggests to input arXiv `eprint` ids without a leading `arXiv:`

> The style supports the arXiv-recommended fields `eprint` and (optionally) `primaryclass`, for example,
>
> ```
> eprint       = "960935712",
> primaryclass = "cs",
> ```

the documentation also links to the arXiv recommendations at https://arxiv.org/help/hypertex/bibstyles.

The documentation does not say anything about articles on the arXiv that are not also published in journals, but given that `@article` produces subpar results and BibTeX warnings

```
Warning--no journal in Mnih13
Warning--no number and no volume in Mnih13
Warning--page numbers missing in both pages and numpages fields in Mnih13
```

I'd probably go for a more generic `@misc`

```
\documentclass[manuscript,screen]{acmart}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Mnih13,
  author    = {V. Mnih and K. Kavukcuoglu and D. Silver and A. Graves
               and I. Antonoglou and D. Wierstra and M. Riedmiller},
  title     = {Playing Atari with Deep Reinforcement Learning},
  year      = {2013},
  eprint    = {1312.5602},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Text~\cite{Mnih13}

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: V. Mnih, K. Kavukcuoglu, D. Silver, A. Graves, I. Antonoglou, D. Wierstra, and M. Riedmiller. 2013. Playing Atari with Deep Reinforcement Learning. arXiv:1312.5602]

`acmart` also comes with a `biblatex` style and with `biblatex` styles I usually recommend using `@online` for arXiv entries not published in a journal, see [Format of @article without journal title field in biblatex bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415115/35864).