# remove "In" field from bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, citing, multiple-citations

I want to cite an archive paper, which doesn't have a journal name. If I do something like this,

```
@article{article,
    author    = "Author",
    title     = "Title",
    year      = "2003",
    url   = "arXiv:000112"
}
```

my bibliography get generated like this:

```
Author. “Title”. In: (2015). URL : arXiv:1409.1556.
```

There"s no journal name in front of **In**. Is it possible to simply remove this "in"?

Comment: Biblatex defines the  `@online` entry type, which would fit better you needs.

Comment: An `@article` always needs to have a `journal`/`journaltitle`. If your arXiv paper hasn't also been published in a journal, it probably shouldn't be an `@article`. You can use `@online` or `@unpublished`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415115/35864

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use "@unpublished"

```
@unpublished{key,
  author = "Author",
  title  = "Title",
  year   = "2003",
  url   = "arXiv:000112"
}
```

which gives:

```
Author. Title. 2003. URL arXiv:000112.
```

Answer (score 1):

To specify the Entry Type use the following syntax

```
\renewbibmacro{in:}{\ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\bibstring{in}\printunit{\intitlepunct}}
}
```

where you can replace "article" with any Entry Type (book, collection, periodical, proceeding . . .).

The empty braces in the second line means replacing "In:" with empty, thus deleting it (Note: you can replace the word "In:" with any other word).

"\bibstring{in}" it's just the word "In", and "\intitlepunct" it's the two points of "In".

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864.

Comment: Note that you can edit previous posts. (I would say it is fairly unusual to post two answers to the same question, especially if the answers are so closely related.)