# Remove 'In' and 'pp' from bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I want to remove the 'In' an 'pp' that is produced in the bibliography. These are some of the commands in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[left=3.50cm, right=3.0cm, top=3.0cm, bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibtest.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

[image]

Comment: On the In question see [Suppress "In:" biblatex](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682). For the pages see [BibLaTeX - How to remove the period after p/pp in Bibliography only](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/277272).

Comment: I agree with Alan about the 'In:', but I would use `\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}` to remove the 'pp.'.

Answer (score 18):

Use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
```

to get rid of the 'pp.' in the bibliography for all types. If you only want that for journal articles, use `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}`.

For the 'in:', have a look at [Suppress "In:" biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864). The following removes the 'in:' only for `@article`

```
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\bibstring{in}%
     \printunit{\intitlepunct}}}
```

*edit*: Updated for `biblatex` 3.15's definition of `in:`.