# Editing a citation style (verbose-ibid), removing the "in :" (article) and changing ":" for a comma (book)

Tags: biblatex

I have two question, they should normally be separate questions, but I think that the answer for both questions will be similar. I want to make modifications in my citation style.

1) for an article, I don't want "in : publicationtitle" to be printed, I only want "publicationtile", no "in :".

2) after the location, I want a comma, not two dots. Eg. Not "New York : Publisher", but "New York, Publisher.

Thanks in advance for your time and skills!

```
\documentclass[MA,french,nonatbib,12pt]{ulthese}

\ifxetex\else \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

 \usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, backend=biber, giveninits=true, 
citepages=omit]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite[381]{sigfridsson}
ipsum\autocite[200]{aristotle:physics}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first requirement, a search would have taken you to [Suppress “In:” biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10686/105447).

As to the colon between location and publisher, it is set in the bibmacro `publisher+location+date` at `standard.bbx`. It is a short one, and we can redefine it with:

```
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
```

In full:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, backend=biber, giveninits=true,
citepages=omit]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10686/105447
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite[381]{sigfridsson}
ipsum\autocite[200]{aristotle:physics}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and your answer, it is much appreciated.