# Suppressing the words "In", "DOI" and "URL" in biblatex reference

Tags: biblatex, doi

I'm using Overleaf with `biblatex`, `backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none`. And I don't want the words "In", "URL" and "DOI" be written out before the actual journal, url or DOI link in my reference.

I get:

> [1] E. Wigner. “On Unitary Representations of the Inhomogeneous Lorentz Group”. In: Annals of Mathematics40.1 (1939), pp. 149–204. URL: http://www.jstor.org/stable/1968551.

But I want:

> [1] E. Wigner. “On Unitary Representations of the Inhomogeneous Lorentz Group”. Annals of Mathematics40.1 (1939), pp. 149–204. http://www.jstor.org/stable/1968551.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please provide a minimal working example with your question; it'll make it much easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your preamble:

```
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
```

Compare these with the default definitions from `biblatex.def` which include "in: ", "URL: ", and DOI: ":

```
\newbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
```

(See also the linked question in @moewe's comment below for further details on suppressing "in:".)

Comment: Plus one of the solutions to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864 for the "in"

Comment: @moewe, oops I missed the in.