# How to remove the "En:" at every bibliography entry?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm writing a document in Spanish with LuaTeX, and using Biber and  BiblaTeX for the bibliography.

The question is every entry appears as:

> JL Schafer. «Multiple Imputation, o prime Statistical Methods in
> Medical Research 8». **En:** (1999).
>
> Andrew C Titman y Linda D Sharples. «Semi-Markov models with
> phase-type sojourn distributions.» En: Biometrics 66 (3 sep. de 2010).

I think that "En:" is quite ugly. It means "At:" in English, but I haven't seen it before in English documents.

How can I remove it?

My header contains this:

```
\usepackage[maxbibnames=3,style=numeric,backend=biber,
   url=false,doi=false, isbn=false]{biblatex} 
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{urlyear} \clearfield{urlmonth}
   \clearfield{pages} \clearfield{eprint}}
```

And my document:

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={BIBLIOGRAFÍA}]
```

Comment: Does [Suppress “In:” biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/5001) help?

Comment: And specifically the `biblatex-ext` solution from that answer.

Comment: Note that the first "en"  looks particularly wrong, because the entry, which is presumably given as an `@article`, does not actually have a `journal` field. I'd consider that incorrect input: `@article`s always have a `journal`. In the second entry, the 'en' doesn't look as bad, because there the `@article` has a `journal`. (That said, many people find `biblatex`'s choice of using 'in:' even for `@article`s questionable, so I'm certainly not against suppressing it as shown in Mico's link, but at least in the Schafer entry something else is up as well.)

Comment: @Mico OK, than works, thank you. Looking for common and small words is difficult.