# Remove "In" from bibliography in biblatex with apa-styple

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I try to remove "In" word from the bibliography with APA-style. I found some comments suggest me to use the renewbibmacro, but it still appears in the bibliography.
This is my sample code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{TExtTemp}
\author{mynameisbee }
\date{November 2020}



\usepackage[
backend=biber,
bibencoding=utf8,
style=apa6,
citestyle=numeric,
firstinits=true,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
url=false,
sorting=none,
clearlang=true,
natbib=true,
intitle=true,
date=year,
uniquelist=false,
maxbibnames=6,
maxcitenames=1,
defernumbers=true
]{biblatex}

%% for a list number index
\makeatletter
\RequireBibliographyStyle{numeric}
\makeatother



\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{title}{\textbf{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\textbf{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,unpublished,misc]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}

%% remove comma in Author name
%\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
%remove "in" out from proceeding
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{}



\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@article{Ellen,
  title={Pathogen-Host Interactions: Antigenic Variation V. Somatic Adaptations},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Signal Processing Systems},
  author={Hsu, Ellen and Du Pasquier, Louis},
  volume={57},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@inproceedings{Pisit,
   title = {Latent Cognizance: {{What}} Machine Really Learns},
  booktitle = {{{ACM}} International Conference Proceeding Series},
  author = {Nakjai, Pisit and Ponsawat, Jiradej and Katanyukul, Tatpong},
  date = {2019},
  pages = {164--170}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Ellen} is a chapter in \cite{Pisit}.

\printbibliography[title=REFERENCES]
\end{document}
```

This is my result. In the red block, "In" word is still appear.
Another question, I want to remove the bracket (green block). How can I remove it?

Thank you for all suggestions. I am sorry for my language.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppress "In:" biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10682/suppress-in-biblatex)

Comment: The macro is `in` not `in:` (no colon :)

Comment: @TomSolid Yes I did, I follow the suggestion, but they use "in:" in renewmacrobib. However, I have used only "in" not "in:". It works. Thank you Guido

Answer (score 1):

[Guido](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16895/guido) has already [pointed out in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570522/remove-in-from-bibliography-in-biblatex-with-apa-styple#comment1437750_570522) that the relevant bibmacro is called `in` in `biblatex-apa6` and not `in:`. So you would need something like

```
\renewbibmacro*{in}{}
```

---

The `booktitle` in the `Pisit` entry looks a bit odd. It sounds more like a `series` than a `booktitle`. Research suggests that

```
@inproceedings{Pisit,
  title     = {Latent Cognizance: What Machine Really Learns},
  booktitle = {AIPR '19: Proceedings of the 2nd International Conference
               on Artificial Intelligence and Pattern Recognition},
  author    = {Nakjai, Pisit and Ponsawat, Jiradej and Katanyukul, Tatpong},
  date      = {2019},
  pages     = {164--170}
}
```

would be much more appropriate. In that case I'd definitely stick to the "in".

Comment: It should be `in` not `in:` in the argument or `\renewbibmacro`

Comment: @Guido Ooops. Fixed, thank you very much.