# Suppress "In" within LyX

Tags: biblatex, lyx

I have a `.bib` file with entries like this:

```
@article{abdulkadirouglu2015expanding,
  title={Expanding {`choice'} in school choice},
  author={Abdulkadiro{\u{g}}lu, Atila and Che, Yeon-Koo and Yasuda, Yosuke},
  journal={American Economic Journal: Microeconomics},
  volume={7},
  number={1},
  pages={1--42},
  year={2015}
}
```

With references in LyX turning out as shown below. I'm happy with it except for the "In".
[image: citation example]

It's not clear to me how to suppress this "In," and I'm not sure how to adapt [solutions like these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10682/suppress-in-biblatex).

My bibliography settings (>Document/Settings/Bibliography) are Style format: Biblatex, Variant: Author-year, the citation and bibliography style is authoryear. I am running LyX 2.3.6.1. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want to suppress the "in:" for `@article` entries I suggest you adapt [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509224/35864) to [Suppress "In:" biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864).

This means that in the *Documents > Settings > Bibliography* settings you need to choose the `biblatex-ext` style that corresponds to your `biblatex` standard style. So instead of `authoryear` you pick

```
ext-authoryear
```

in *Biblatex citation style* and *Biblatex bibliography style* (red circles in screenshot below, you can use the <kbd>Match</kbd> button to set the bibliography to the same style as the citation style).

Then you add

```
articlein=false,
```

to the *Options* (green circle).

[image: Screenshot of LyX document options with authoryear-ext selected as bibliography and citation style and articlein=false, option set]

Press OK and recompile your document to obtain

[image: Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998). “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

from a simple document citing `biblatex-examples`'s `sigfridsson` entry.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for general entries, too? I.e., if I have misc, techreport's, etc? It looks like biblatex-ext only offers this option for articles.

Comment: @shaha For `@misc` and `@techreport` there shouldn't be an "in:" in the first place. And for entry types beside `@article` that normally have an "in:" (`@inbook`, `@incollection`, `@inproceedings`) you generally want to retain the "in:". As I say in my linked answer, if you want to get rid of "in:" for all types, you need a different approach, but really I don't think you need/want that.