# Removing the word "In" for citations in classicthesis

Tags: biblatex

I am using `classicthesis` for my master's thesis. My supervisor told me to remove the "In: *journalname*" in the bibliography for references appearing in journals, and that "In:" should only be used for book entries. However, I do not understand how I can make this change while at the same time keeping the nice `numeric-comp`-like citations ([1-3] instead of [1,2,3]) and a bibliography that is numbered (not author-year style, but [1], [2], ....). I suspect this is where the magic should happen, but I just cannot make it work:

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\PassOptionsToPackage{%
%backend=biber, % Instead of bibtex
backend=bibtex8,
bibencoding=ascii,%
language=auto,%
style=numeric-comp,%
%style=authoryear-comp, % Author 1999, 2010
%bibstyle=numeric,dashed=false, % dashed: substitute rep. author with ---
sorting=none, % name, year, title
maxbibnames=10, % default: 3, et al.
%backref=true,%
natbib=true % natbib compatibility mode (\citep and \citet still work)
}{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

Comment: Moewe's or the accepted answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10682/suppress-in-biblatex

Comment: Oh thank you so so much!