# Bibliography has "in" that I would like to remove

Tags: biblatex

I use a template to write my thesis and I am stuck in a minor issue. In the bibliography, after the authors and the name of paper, it writes **"In:"**.  This *In* is only displayed in the papers, and it is not displayed n the bibliography for books. How do I get rid of it?

I found a section on the template which I believe is related to this issue, but I cannot pinpoint it:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage[
      isbn=false,
      doi=false,
      url=true,
      maxbibnames=99, % Effectively ensure all authors are listed
      language=american, % ... English
      %style=trad-alpha,%change style to numeric
      style=numeric,
      maxalphanames=4 % Only use first 4 names for an initials key
      ]{biblatex}
    \setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000}
    \setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}
    \setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{9000}
    \AtEveryBibitem{
      % remove abstract from bibliographic entries
      \clearfield{abstract}%
      % do not show both eprint/doi and url
      \iffieldundef{eprint}{}{\clearfield{url}}%
    }
    
    \newcommand{\makebibliography}{%
      \ifdefined\pdfbookmark
        % If hyperref is loaded, this will help us to more
        % easily navigate to the bibliography
        % \pdfbookmark[0]{Bibliography}{bib}%
      \fi
      \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
    }
```

The full template is here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/technion-iit-thesis-template/rzqpztzgppwz

Comment: Since links tend to rot over time, we very much prefer to have (full but minimal) example code listed here, then your question will also be useful for others in the future.

Comment: `biblatex` only shows "in" if the work you are citing is part of a larger (body of) work. You get an "in" if you cite an article/paper in a journal. You also get an in if you cite a paper/chapter in a collection or book. Many prescriptive styles do not want an "in" for journal articles, but almost all styles I know will want an "in" for chapters. The already linked https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864 has an answer to suppress the "in" only for articles and to suppress it for all types.

Comment: @moewe, Yes, this solves my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to change characters that separate the individual details of a source.
It was getting way too complicated and I stuck to testing all the different preset bibliography styles. They can then also be manually altered to exclude or include additional information.

Here an example to get you started. It is what I ended up using:

```
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex,isbn=false,url=false,minnames=5,maxnames=6]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify how your answer addresses the OP's question, which was about how to suppress the "In: " prefix that biblatex places ahead of the name of the journal for "papers", i.e., for entries of type `@article`.