# Custom bibliography style (natbib like) with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, natbib

I have just switched from natbib to biblatex, and I am trying to restore some of the previous layouts. I have this import now:

```
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=verbose-ibid,isbn=false]{biblatex}
```

which gives me the citation style I want. However, for journals the bibliography style changed in an unfortunate way. Before it looked like this:

> Charles, D. (1965), ‘Entr’acte: “Formal” or “Informal” Music?’, *The
>   Musical Quarterly* **51**(1), 144–165.

Now it looks like this (I managed to get rid of the "In:"):

> Charles, Daniel. “Entr’acte: “Formal” or “Informal” Music?”, *The
>   Musical Quarterly* 51.1, pp. 144–165.

I would like to keep a few things from the new style, like full first name, but otherwise revert to the natbib style, with date in the front, title in single inverted commas, volume in bold and number parantheses. Like this:

> Charles, Daniel (1965), ‘Entr’acte: “Formal” or “Informal” Music?’,
>   *The Musical Quarterly* **51**(1), pp. 144–165.

How would I achieve this?

---

**EDIT**

I managed to get the year in the beginning by using diverging citation and bibliography styles:

```
\usepackage[natbib=true,citestyle=verbose-ibid,isbn=false,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

I followed the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6743/biblatex-changing-the-order-of-entries). I can use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{(#1)}
```

to make the volume bold and put the number in parentheses. But several macros don't exist here. I had to use `\textbf` instead of `\mkbibbold` (unknown macro).

Moreover, I can't disappear the point between volume and number, now it's

> Charles, Daniel (1965), “Entr’acte: “Formal” or “Informal” Music?”
>   *The Musical Quarterly* **51**.(1), pp. 144–165.

If I try

```
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
  \printfield{volume}%
%  \setunit*{\adddot}% DELETED
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
```

I get this error:

```
LaTeX error: \abx@macro@cite:labelyear+extrayear undefined.
```

Comment: As `\mkbibbold` is defined in `biblatex` v1.7, your version is perhaps outdated, which may also be the reason for other errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following was tested using `biblatex` v1.7 and biber v0.9:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[citestyle=verbose-ibid,bibstyle=authoryear,isbn=false,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{`#1'}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{%
  }{%
    \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}%
  }%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
%  \setunit*{\adddot}% DELETED
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Cha65,
  author = {Charles, Daniel},
  year = {1965},
  title = {Entr’acte: “Formal” or “Informal” Music?},
  journaltitle = {The Musical Quarterly},
  volume = {51},
  number = {1},
  pages = {144--165},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok. I will try to see if I can update biblatex on this system. With my current version it doesn't work, unfortunately...